# 3-dimensional histogram in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots, matlab, import

I have a simple 3d histogram

[image]

which I want to import into pgfplots, e.g. using matlab2tikz or by hand.

PGFplots does not offer 3d histograms.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: 3-D histograms convey very little information and can be misleading. Consider changing the plot to a different type.

Comment: As a concrete example : In a slightly larger domain, quite possibly, it can happen that the closer yellow bars are longer than the distant red ones. Consider switching to a mesh surface e.g. that `pgfplots` offer.

Comment: You're both right, but where I'm using it the data itself is random and a 3d histogram puts an emphasis to the discrete nature of a rainflow matrix.

Comment: @severin: How did you manage to hide the bars with zero counts?

Comment: @Jake They are probably having `NaN` values.

Comment: @Jake: Yes, it's a colormap. I used a function (rfmatrix) which came with the rainflow package: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3026-rainflow-counting-algorithm

Comment: Severin, I have resolved and fixed the feature request discussed by @Jake and you. Would you mind if I commit a copy of your image to the pgfplots git repo to have a unit test?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Of course not.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides While 3D histograms usually are evil, with `view={0}{90}`, they'd be a great way to visualise scalar fields. Currently there is no correct way to do this with pgfplots, hence (+1). I want this as well.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `\addplot3 graphics` to include an image in `pgfplots`. This allows you to use `pgfplots` for drawing the axes and to add annotations using the data coordinate system.

If you have saved a plot from Matlab as an image called `3dcolumnchart.png`, for example, the following code

```
\addplot3 graphics[points={%
(-4.4449,4.6547,0) => (110.814,167.827)
(-4.633,-4.5186,0) => (264.187,74.679)
(4.5829,-4.5216,0) => (470.558,145.343)
(-0.45821,-0.43355,1157) => (287.474,379.016)
}] {3dcolumnchart.png};
\node at (axis cs:-1.5,0.5,490) [inner sep=0pt, pin={[pin edge={thick,black},align=left]145:Interesting\\Data Point}] {};
```

will generate

[image]

For this, you need to provide the mapping from the data coordinate system to the figure coordinate system for four points. You can do this by finding the data coordinates for the points using the "Data Cursor" in Matlab, and finding the figure coordinates (in `pt`) for the same points in an image editor like GIMP. However, this can quickly become a bit tedious.

I've written a Matlab script called `pgfplotscsconversion.m` that allows you to click on four points in the Matlab figure, and the mapping will be written to the Matlab command prompt.

Here's an example of how I arrived at the above figure.

1. Create the Matlab plot

   ```
   hist3(randn(10000,2)) % some random data
   set(get(gca,'child'),'FaceColor','interp','CDataMode','auto'); % colors
   set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto') % make sure the "print" paper format is the same as the screen paper format
   ```
2. Save the following code as `pgfplotscsconversion.m`

   ```
   function pgfplotscsconversion

   % Hook into the Data Cursor "click" event
   h = datacursormode(gcf);
   set(h,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn,'SnapToDataVertex','off');
   datacursormode on

   % select four points in plot using mouse


   % The function that gets called on each Data Cursor click
   function [txt] = myupdatefcn(obj,event_obj)

   % Get the screen resolution, in dots per inch
   dpi = get(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch');

   % Get the click position in pixels, relative to the lower left of the
   % screen
   screen_location=get(0,'PointerLocation');

   % Get the position of the plot window, relative to the lower left of
   % the screen
   figurePos = get(gcf,'Position');

   % Get the data coordinates of the cursor
   pos = get(event_obj,'Position');

   % Format the data and figure coordinates. The factor "72.27/dpi" is
   % necessary to convert from pixels to TeX points (72.27 poins per inch)
   display(['(',num2str(pos(1)),',',num2str(pos(2)),',',num2str(pos(3)),') => (',num2str((screen_location(1)-figurePos(1))*72.27/dpi),',',num2str((screen_location(2)-figurePos(2))*72.27/dpi),')'])

   % Format the tooltip display
   txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1))],['Y: ',num2str(pos(2))],['Z: ',num2str(pos(3))]};
   ```

   Run `pgfplotscsconversion`, click on four points in your plot. Preferably select non-colinear points near the edges of the plot. Copy and paste the four lines that were written to the Matlab command window.
3. Export the plot as an image

   ```
   axis off
   print -dpng matlabout -r400 % PNG called "matlabout.png" with 400 dpi resolution
   ```

   If you want to use vector PDF output, you'll have to set the paper size to match the figure size yourself, since the PDF driver doesn't automatically adjust the size:

   ```
   currentScreenUnits=get(gcf,'Units')     % Get current screen units
   currentPaperUnits=get(gcf,'PaperUnits') % Get current paper units
   set(gcf,'Units',currentPaperUnits)      % Set screen units to paper units
   plotPosition=get(gcf,'Position')        % Get the figure position and size
   set(gcf,'PaperSize',plotPosition(3:4))  % Set the paper size to the figure size
   set(gcf,'Units',currentScreenUnits)     % Restore the screen units

   print -dpdf matlabout      % PDF called "matlabout.pdf"
   ```
4. Remove the white background of the image, for example using the ImageMagick command

   ```
   convert matlabout.png -transparent white 3dcolumnchart.png
   ```
5. Include the image in your `pgfplots` axis. If you selected points on the plot corners, your `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` should be set automatically, otherwise you'll have to provide those yourself. Also, you'll need to adjust the `width` and `height` of the plot to get the right vertical placement of the plot.

   ```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[3d box,xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,width=9cm,height=9.25cm,grid=both, minor z tick num=1]
   \addplot3 graphics[points={%
   (-4.4449,4.6547,0) => (110.814,167.827)
   (-4.633,-4.5186,0) => (264.187,74.679)
   (4.5829,-4.5216,0) => (470.558,145.343)
   (-0.45821,-0.43355,1157) => (287.474,379.016)
   }]
   {3dcolumnchart.png};
   \node at (axis cs:-1.5,0.5,490) [inner sep=0pt, pin={[pin edge={thick,black},align=left]145:Interesting\\Data Point}] {};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Yet another secret weapon! Quite nice.

Comment: Good work! Would you mind if I copy your matlab script into the pgfplots manual?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: By all means, please do! I'd be honoured

Comment: This is really nice. Unfortunately it does not quite seem to work with my example: http://imgur.com/CuAPy Is this because of the different domains?

Comment: @severin: You need to adjust the `width` and `height` values of your plot manually to make the axes start at zero. Also, something seems to be wrong with your grid lines. What `axis` options do you use?

Comment: I used your code, removing the x,y mins/maxs so it fits automatically, but in z-direction it does not. Worse are the axis. Changing width and height does not affect this.
The code: http://pastebin.com/geVhb6rp and the image: http://imgur.com/RtvaW

Comment: @severin: Hmm, that's interesting. Would you mind uploading an ascii version of your matrix (or a similar one with dummy data)?

Comment: @Jake I could provide it, but the plot is created using a special function. So the easiest way is: 1. download http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3026-rainflow-counting-algorithm 2. run rfdemo2.m it'll immediately plot you the same. I guess the reason lies in the different domains: yours a identically for x,y. mine not. And maybe a note should be added, that changing the plot window size affects the result. btw thanks for your efforts!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3222/discussion-between-jake-and-severin)

Answer (score 52):

I managed to achieve a 3-dimensional histogram effect by repeating the coordinates. I just repeat each x,y combination 4 times, once for each of the 4 possible bar tops it could appear in.

For example, the code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    view = {120}{35},% important to draw x,y in increasing order
    xmin = 0,
    ymin = 0,
    xmax = 3,
    ymax = 3,
    zmin = 0,
    unbounded coords = jump,
    colormap={pos}{color(0cm)=(white); color(6cm)=(blue)}
    ]
    \addplot3[surf,mark=none] coordinates {
        (0,0,0) (0,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,1,0) (0,2,nan) (0,2,nan) (0,3,nan) (0,3,nan)

        (0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,2) (0,1,3) (0,2,3) (0,2,1) (0,3,1) (0,3,0)

        (1,0,0) (1,0,2) (1,1,2) (1,1,3) (1,2,3) (1,2,1) (1,3,1) (1,3,0)

        (1,0,0) (1,0,0) (1,1,0) (1,1,6) (1,2,6) (1,2,0) (1,3,0) (1,3,0)

        (2,0,nan) (2,0,nan) (2,1,0) (2,1,6) (2,2,6) (2,2,0) (2,3,nan) (2,3,nan)

        (2,0,0) (2,0,1) (2,1,1) (2,1,0) (2,2,0) (2,2,0) (2,3,nan) (2,3,nan)

        (3,0,0) (3,0,1) (3,1,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,nan) (3,2,nan) (3,3,nan) (3,3,nan)

        (3,0,0) (3,0,0) (3,1,0) (3,1,0) (3,2,nan) (3,2,nan) (3,3,nan) (3,3,nan)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

The 0 z-coordinate values above are meant to have the same value as `zmin` and the view has to be set such that the points with lower x and y coordinates are drawn first.

I don't know how to make the colour of the sides of the bars the same as the top, hence the monochrome colormap.

A larger example can be seen here

[image]

This is from some data I produced in python. To save it to a file, I had to add a few for loops that make sure all the points at the border are set to have z value equal to zmin. The function below takes the x, y mesh stored in `x` and `y`. The respective z values are in `z`, a list of `len(x) - 1` lists of length `len(y) - 1`. It writes to a file `output` that can be included with `\addplot3 file {}`. It assumes that there are no NaN values and sets the z values along the border to `zmin`.

```py
import csv

def make3dhistogram(x, y, z, zmin, output):
    writer = csv.writer(open(output, 'wb'), delimiter=' ')
    i = 0
    for j in range(len(y)):
        writer.writerow((x[i], y[j], zmin))
        writer.writerow((x[i], y[j], zmin))
    for i in range(len(x)-1):        
        writer.writerow((x[i], y[0], zmin))
        for j in range(len(y)-1):
            writer.writerow((x[i], y[j], z[i][j]))
            writer.writerow((x[i], y[j+1], z[i][j]))            
        writer.writerow((x[i], y[len(y)-1], zmin))
        writer.writerow([])
        writer.writerow((x[i+1], y[0], zmin))
        for j in range(len(y)-1):
            writer.writerow((x[i+1], y[j], z[i][j]))
            writer.writerow((x[i+1], y[j+1], z[i][j]))          
        writer.writerow((x[i+1], y[len(y)-1], zmin))
        writer.writerow([])

    i = len(x)-1
    for j in range(len(y)):
        writer.writerow((x[i], y[j], zmin))
        writer.writerow((x[i], y[j], zmin))
```

So for example

```py
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [0,1,2,3]
z = [[2,3,1], [0, 6, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
make3dhistogram(x, y, z, 0.0, 'data')
```

produces the simple plot above, this time with a grid on the z plane as none of the points are skipped.

Comment: Wow, that's very impressive! I assume you didn't code the coordinates for the large plot by hand. Would you mind explaining how you generated the coordinates?

Comment: You can get the sides in the same color as the top by using `shader=flat corner`. To get the connecting lines in a darker shade of the fill color, you can use `draw=mapped color!80!black`.

Comment: Thank you @Jake. I added a brief description how I produced the input file from x,y,z values.

Comment: The Python code is not complete, could you please provide the missing parts?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I completed the code, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks! This works particularly well with "shader=faceted interp" which makes color vary over the height of the bar. (I don't think this was an option when the answer was first posted.) Also worth considering is "faceted color=black, opacity=0.2, fill opacity=1" for opaque bars with translucent lines.

Answer (score 23):

[matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022) now fully supports 3D histograms.
This

```
load seamount
dat = [-y,x]; % Grid corrected for negative y-values
hist3(dat) % Draw histogram in 2D
n = hist3(dat); % Extract histogram data;
                % default to 10x10 bins
view([-37.5, 30]);
```

gives

[image: matlab2tikz output]

Comment: Oh wow, that's impressive! It works really well, even allowing arbitrary `view` parameters. The color can be improved a bit by setting `shader=flat corner,draw=mapped color!70!black` in the `\addplot3` options.

Comment: It seems that this approach struggles with the OP's use case, though: The size of 35x35 columns doesn't compile with `pdflatex` due to memory limitations, and compiling with `lualatex` (which works) reveals that there are z-buffering errors due to the reversed y axis.

Comment: The z buffering problem is a bug in pgfplots; providing `y dir=reverse` will work well with the next pgfplots stable (i.e. *not* with 1.5.1).

Comment: @Jake Oh this shouldn't happen. :/ Is the MATLAB code of the OP's figure out there?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger frankly, I didn't change the code; it just worked with `surf()`s logic.

Comment: @Nico: Yeah, the OP ran `rfdemo2.m` from the `rainflow` package: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3026-rainflow-counting-algorithm. There's a bit of a discussion in the comments to my answer, and the chat that is linked there.

Answer (score 11):

I was not satisfied with the previous answers and therefore created my own solution.

- Jake's solution is present in the documentation but first I couldn't make it work, second it does not generate a image from data, which is what I want from Tikz.
- I worked on Anton's answer. It took me some time to figure out the way coordinates were organized to put it in a automatic code reading data from a file. But even if I managed to do so I couldn't overcome the impossibility to create a personalized coloring. I was then left with the choice between a monochrome plot like Anton shows, and a figure where the top face of a bar has a different color than its sides.
- I don't think that, as Nico said, matlab2tikz now fully supports 3D histograms, or I wouldn't have come here in the first place. I tried matlab2tikz on my picture given by matlab using 'bar3', and the result was bugged.

=> I offer a solution where I got rid of  `\begin{axis}` and the constraints like `\edef`, `\temp` and `\noexpand`, that I had to use to make Anton's way work automatically.

Here is the minimal code :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{DataTest.dat}{\firsttable}                   
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{DataTest.dat}   
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}   

    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 2}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\maxZ\pgfplotsretval    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Zscale}{4/\maxZ}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,4 cm)}]

\colorlet{redhsb}[hsb]{red}     %
\colorlet{bluehsb}[hsb]{blue}   % 

\foreach \p in {1,...,\rows}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\p}{[index] 0}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\x\pgfplotsretval 
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\p}{[index] 1}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\y\pgfplotsretval 
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\p}{[index] 2}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\z\pgfplotsretval 

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\teinte}{100-((\z/\maxZ)*100)}
        \colorlet{col}[rgb]{bluehsb!\teinte!redhsb}   
         % Visible faces from original view
            \fill[col] (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\z);
                \draw[black](\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\z);
            \fill[col] (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z);
                \draw[black](\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z);
          % Top face
           \fill[col] (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y+0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,\z) ;
            \draw[black] (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y+0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\z) -- (\x+0.5,\y-0.5,\z) -- (\x-0.5,\y-0.5,\z);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using the file DataTest.dat containing:

```
X   Y   Z
3   3   1   %max

1   3   1
1   2   0.8
1   1   0.7
2   3   0.75
2   2   0.5
2   1   0.25
3   3   0.3
3   2   0.1
3   1   0
```

Which gives the following picture :

[image]

To improve the picture and to have more comments on the code, here is a more detailed solution :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableread{DataTest.dat}{\firsttable}           % Read
      \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{DataTest.dat} 
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}       % Put the number of row minus one in \rows, 
                                                            %     to use : \foreach \p in {0,...,\rows}
% Assign variables max
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 0}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\maxX\pgfplotsretval 
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 1}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\maxY\pgfplotsretval 
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 2}\of{\firsttable} 
        \let\maxZ\pgfplotsretval 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Zscale}{4/\maxZ} % contain the values of z between 0 and 4 cm 
                                       %      (provided that they are positiv)

% Defining by hand the axis
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,\Zscale cm)}]

% Defining hsb color to have a color scale
\colorlet{redhsb}[hsb]{red}     %
\colorlet{bluehsb}[hsb]{blue}   % 

% Drawing the system of axes
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node [black,left] {x};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node [black,left] {y};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1/\Zscale) node [black,left] {z};

% Write unit on x and y
\foreach \p in {1,...,\maxX}{
    \draw {(\p,0,0)} node[right] {\p};
    % Draw the grid
    \foreach \q in {1,...,\maxY}{
        \draw[black] (\p-0.5,\q-0.5,0) -- (\p+0.5,\q-0.5,0) -- (\p+0.5,\q+0.5,0) -- (\p-0.5,\q+0.5,0) -- (\p-0.5,\q-0.5,0);
        }
}
\foreach \p in {1,...,\maxY}{
    \draw {(\maxX+1,\p,0)} node[left] {\p};
}

\foreach \p in {1,...,\rows}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\p}{[index] 0}\of{\firsttable}    % The order in which the bars are drawn is determined by
        \let\x\pgfplotsretval                                   %    the order of the lines in the data file.
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\p}{[index] 1}\of{\firsttable}    % And as the drawings just pile up, the last one just goes
        \let\y\pgfplotsretval                                   %    on top of the previous drawings.
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\p}{[index] 2}\of{\firsttable}    % The order here works with chosen view angle, if you
        \let\z\pgfplotsretval                                   %    change the angle, you might have to change it.

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{0.8/2} % half the width of the bars

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\teinte}{100-((\z/\maxZ)*100)}
        \colorlet{col}[rgb]{bluehsb!\teinte!redhsb}   
        % Unseen faces from orginal view, but if you change the angle ....
            %\fill[col] (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z);
            %   \draw[black] (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z);
            %\fill[col] (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z);
            %   \draw[black](\x-\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z);
         % Visible faces from original view
            \fill[col] (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z);
                \draw[black](\x+\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z);
            \fill[col!60!gray] (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z);
                \draw[black](\x+\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,0) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z);
          % Top face
           \fill[top color=col!40!gray, bottom color=col!80!gray] (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) ;
            \draw[black] (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y+\w,\z) -- (\x+\w,\y-\w,\z) -- (\x-\w,\y-\w,\z);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the image :

[image: BeautifulHistogram]

As you can see I added some features which are detailed in the comments of the code.

I hope it can help someone, thanks for reading.

To complete this, here is the Matlab code I used to generate the data file from the data in the matrix `MAC`.

```
fileID = fopen('DataOutMac.dat','w');
  MaxMAC = max(MAC(:));

  %Header
    fprintf(fileID,'X \t\t Y \t\t Z \n');
  %Maximums
    fprintf(fileID,['' num2str(size(MAC,1)) ' \t\t ' num2str(size(MAC,2)) ' \t\t ' num2str(MaxMAC) ' \t\t %% max \n \n']);
  %All the values
    for i=1:size(MAC,1)
      for j=size(MAC,2):-1:1
        if MAC(i,j)>(MaxMAC/10000)  % To remove the smallest bars
            fprintf(fileID,['' num2str(i) ' \t\t ' num2str(j) ' \t\t%12.8f \n'], MAC(i,j));%'%12.8f\n'], MAC(i,j));
        end
      end
    end
fclose(fileID);
```

Edit to answer the comment:

-First, the reason why I am here in the first place : on the left is matlab's output and on the right matlab2tikz's result.

[image: Matlab2tikz_Result]

-Second, here is the result of one of my tries of jake's solution.

[image: PNG-Solution]

Comment: This is nice but very limited as you might try out. I don't understand your complaints about other answers. I used matlab2tikz with no problems. Can you include your data somewhere? So we can have a look. Because your solution, with all respect, exceedingly manual.

Comment: Thank you for your interest @percusse, I edited my post to add results given by the previous solutions. Why do you find my code manual ? You can just give your data in a file like the 'DataTest.dat' and it would give you an image. I am new to this forum, I saw that my post had been edited by pluton, is he some sort of moderator, or is this site working like a wiki page ? If so how can I see the modifications ?

Comment: @LMT-PhD, how I like your solution, but how can I add a "colormap" say on the left side of the figure to act as legend? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On my installation, I had to remove `\usepackage{pgfplotstable} \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` (I was getting Lua errors, even with `lualatex` otherwise), then it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 8):

**WITHOUT EXTERNAL PROGRAMS**: Just produce a scatter plot of cubes with the height of the code depending on the data. (I stole the code from [here](https://texwelt.de/wissen/antwort_link/21902/), but the author of the code is fine with me sharing it here ;-)

**UPDATE**: @sporc found a bug and helped me to improve the code. Thanks! See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435234/121799) for further additions to the code.

If you run this, LaTeX will tell you which prefactor to insert. I could not do this in a simple way because of the expansion issues, essentially because pgfplots is setting the scales only after it is done with the plots. In this example, it would be possible to avoid this by doing an empty plot first. But then the code would blow up and the user would modify things twice, or do some other crazy things, such that I feel adjusting one single number is the lesser evil.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102770/121799
\def\pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/iflessthan/.@cmd}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\pgfeov
}%
\def\pgfplotsmulticmpthree#1#2#3#4#5#6\do#7#8{%
    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#1}{#4}{%
        % first key <:
        #7%
    }{%
        \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#4}{#1}{%
            % first key >:
            #8%
        }{%
            % first key ==:
            \pgfplotsset{float <}%
            \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#2}{#5}{%
                % second key <
                #7%
            }{%
                \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#5}{#2}{%
                    % second key >
                    #8%
                }{%
                    % second key ==
                    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
                    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#3}{#6}{%
                        % third key <
                        #7%
                    }{%
                        % third key >=
                        #8%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
x,y,color,myvalue
2,3,1,100
4,3,2,3
2,7,3,0.75
7,7,4,45
8,5,2,3
2,5,1,10
4,-4,2,1
4,1,3,75
5,-1,4,4
5,2,2,3
1,-2,1,10
2,5,2,5
3,-8,3,75
4,5,4,42
7,-2,2,2
}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
        create col/assign/.code={%
            \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
        }
    },
    sort key=sortkey,
    sort cmp={%
        iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
            \edef\temp{#1#2}%
            \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
        },
    },
    sort,
    columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
    columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
        view={120}{40},
        width=320pt,
        height=280pt,
        z buffer=none,
        xmin=-1,xmax=9,
        ymin=-10,ymax=8,
        zmin=0,zmax=200,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        ztick={0,100,200},
        zticklabels={0,50,100}, % here one has to "cheat"
        % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
        % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
        % values
        xtick=data,
        extra tick style={grid=major},
        ytick=data,
        grid=minor,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        zlabel={$z$},
        minor tick num=1,
        point meta=explicit,
        colormap name=viridis,
        scatter/use mapped color={
            draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
        execute at begin plot={}            
        ]
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
\typeout{Kindly\space\space consider\space setting\space the\space 
        prefactor\space of\space z\space to\space \conv}};      
\addplot3 [visualization depends on={
0.9952*z \as \myz}, % you'll get told how to adjust the prefactor
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz pt},%
scatter,only marks,
mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
 table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
 expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
 meta expr={\thisrow{color}}
        ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution! But there are two things: 1) When Changing the `zmax` to match a smaller max z value, the bars seem to float, 2)In your example the yellow bar is behind the purple bar, which doesn't look very nice

Comment: @sporc As for the second point: very good catch, thanks!!! I updated the thingy, luckily a simple sort did the job. (It is amazing what Christian Feuersänger created!) As for your first point, I do not really understand what you are saying, but to first approximation I would say: just don't make `zmax` too small. The whole post is in a sense a big cheat: I just put cubes of different length at the various positions, and you'll always be able to find a scenario where that fails.

Comment: this looks better now, for the first point I created a followup questions, it would be nice iif you could take a look ;)
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435193/3d-histogram-without-external-programs
thanks

Comment: @sporc I will remove my comment above since things are now answered in your follow-up question. Of course, ultimately there might be even more things that need to be adjusted such as the width and depth of the bars. One could compute the value of those, too, I think, so I am wondering if you want to append this to your nice question.

Comment: Yes this would be the next step. Do you have an idea how to implement an automatic adjustion of the width and depth of the bars? I edited my question ;)

Comment: @sporc I have updated the answer there. Actually I am wondering if there is a nice way to synchronize these posts because I do not want to change the posts twice in case of further updates.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the many solutions and this being an old post, the initial problem/question, i.e. I have a MATLAB 3D histogram and want to put it in a nice tikz environment, is not solved. This is maybe because in the newer MATLAB versions the function **histogram2** was introduced, but who knows.

Being myself in this situation, and considering I tend to dislike pgfplots and prefer plain TikZ (easier to make changes later, more low level and understandable) I propose the following MATLAB function that creates a nice TikZ figure from an histogram2 object.

```
    function histogram2tikz( h, file  )
    %HISTOGRAM2TIKZ
    if nargin < 2
        file = 'figure.tex';
    end

        % Open file for writing / re-writing
        fid = fopen( file, 'w' );

        % Collect relevant variables from histogram
        hvals = h.Values;
        xed = h.XBinEdges;
        yed = h.YBinEdges;
        colorBars = 'blue';
        clear h

        % Begin 3D tikz picture
        fprintf( fid, ...
        '%% Begin 3D tikz picture \n \\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{100} \n \\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, yscale = %f] \n', ...
        5/max( hvals(:) ) );

        % Plot axis and grid
            % Axis
            maxx = max( xed ); maxy = max( yed ); maxval = max( hvals(:) );
            minx = min( xed ); miny = min( yed );
            fprintf( fid, ...
            '%% Plot axis and grid \n\t%% Axis \n  \\draw[->] (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$} ;\n', ...
            minx, miny, minx, maxy );
            fprintf( fid, ...
            '\\draw[->] (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0) node[anchor=north]{$x$};\n', ...
            minx, miny, maxx, miny );
            fprintf( fid, ...
            '\\draw[->] (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,%f);\n', ...
            minx, miny, minx, miny, maxval );
            % Grid
            fprintf( fid, '\t%%Grid and ticks\n');
            for ii = 1:length( xed )
                fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[gray,thin] (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0);\n', ...
                xed(ii), miny, xed(ii), maxy );
            end
            for ii = 1:length( yed )
                fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[gray,thin] (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0);\n', ...
                minx, yed(ii), maxx, yed(ii) );
            end

        % Plot bars
        for ii = 1:length( xed )-1
            for jj = 1:length( yed )-1
                bar( xed(ii:ii+1), yed(jj:jj+1), hvals(ii,jj), fid, colorBars );
            end
        end

        % Finish tikzfigure and close file
        fprintf( fid, ...
        '%% Finish tikz picture \n \\end{tikzpicture}' );
        fclose( fid );

    end

    function bar( xbin, ybin, h, fid, cB )
        fprintf( fid, '%%Bar with edges x: %.2f,%.2f; edges y: %.2f,%.2f ; height: %.2f\n', ...
                 xbin(1), xbin(2), ybin(1), ybin(2), h );
        if h>0
            % Draw bottom square
            fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[thin] (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0) -- (%f,%f,0) -- cycle;\n', ...
                xbin(1), ybin(1), ...
                xbin(1), ybin(2), ...
                xbin(2), ybin(2), ...
                xbin(2), ybin(1) );
            % Draw back faces
            fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[thin,fill=%s!70!black] (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- cycle;\n', ...
                cB, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(1), 0, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(1), 0, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(1), h, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(1), h ); 
            fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[thin,fill=%s!70!black] (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- cycle;\n', ...
                cB, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(1), 0, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(2), 0, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(2), h, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(1), h ); 
            % Draw front faces
            fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[thin,fill=%s!70!black] (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- cycle;\n', ...
                cB, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(2), 0, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(2), 0, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(2), h, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(2), h ); 
            fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\draw[thin,fill=%s!70!black] (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- cycle;\n', ...
                cB, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(1), 0, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(2), 0, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(2), h, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(1), h ); 
            % Draw top square
            fprintf( fid, ...
                '\\path[fill=%s] (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- (%f,%f,%f) -- cycle;\n', ...
                cB, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(1), h, ...
                xbin(1), ybin(2), h, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(2), h, ...
                xbin(2), ybin(1), h );  
        end
    end
```

A minimal working example would be running in MATLAB

```
% Generate Multivariate normal data
d = mvnrnd( [0,0], eye(2), 200 );
% Get Histogram
h = histogram2( d(:,1), d(:,2) );
% Generate TikZ figure
histogram2tikz(h)
```

and having in the same folder the minimal LaTeX document

```
\documentclass{article}
% Graphics in tikz format
\usepackage{tikz}
% 3D tikz, simple library
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%% Document begins
\begin{document}
    \input{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: Simple histogram in two steps]

The great thing about this is that then you can get into the generated file and change colors for every bar, as well as anything other you might want, in a pretty straightforward manner if you know your basic TikZ. For example, replacing all `fill=blue!70!black` by `fill=blue!70!black,fill opacity=0.6` and change the `yscale` for it to look nicer, you get
[image: Simple histogram with transparency in three steps]

Comment: +1 because you're the first one to use opacity

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the fact that this is a confusing perspective, you can create a 3D bar diagram with pgfplots like this:

The idea is to use `mark=cube*` and manipulate the `cube/size z` in such a way that the desired 3D bars are created.
Similar to the answer from @user121799, with the difference that reading out and using the unit length in the z-direction should be automated.

If one put e.g. `cube/size z=4mm`, so the cube dimensions grow from its room position by `2mm` and by `-2mm` in the z-direction.
So they have to be positioned at 
`x=X, y=Y, z expr={0.5*\thisrow{Z}}`.

The correct height of the cubes can be made with

```
visualization depends on={\thisrow{Z} \as \zvalue}, 
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\barheight}{\zunitlength*\zvalue},
/pgfplots/cube/size z=\barheight },
```

where the `zunitlength` is found with

```
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{   \pgfmathsetglobalmacro{\zunitlength}{\y1}   }    };
```

Note: It turns out that it makes sense to set `zmax=\zMax`, where this maximum z-value `\zMax` can be determined in the form

```
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsNo}{\pgfplotsretval-1}  
%Number of Rows: \RowsNo
\pgfmathsetmacro\zMax{0}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\RowsNo}{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{Z}\of{\datatable}
\pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval > \zMax ? \pgfplotsretval : \zMax}
\xdef\zMax{\pgfmathresult}
}
%Maximum z-Axis: \zMax
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\pgfmathsetglobalmacro#1#2{\pgfmathparse{#2}%
\global\let#1\pgfmathresult}

\pgfplotsset{
colormap = {mycolormap}{
color(0)  = (blue!50!black); 
color(1) = (purple);
color(2) = (green!55!black);
color(3) = (brown);
color(4) = (blue!66)
color(5) = (violet)
},
colormap name=mycolormap,
%colormap name=viridis
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
X,   Y,    Z
2,    0,   4
1,    0,   5
0,    1,   10
3,    1,   1
1,    1,   3
2,    1,   0
1,    2,   0
2,    2,   5
2,    3,   6
1,    4,   7
1,    5,   11
}{\datatable}

% z-Maximum determination ==================
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsNo}{\pgfplotsretval-1}  
%Number of rows: \RowsNo

\pgfmathsetmacro\zMax{0}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\RowsNo}{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{Z}\of{\datatable}
\pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval > \zMax ? \pgfplotsretval : \zMax}
\xdef\zMax{\pgfmathresult}
}
%Maximum z-Axis: \zMax
% ============================

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
%height=2cm,  width=7cm, 
% view={120}{40}, x dir=reverse,
xmin=0, 
ymin=0,
zmin=0, zmax=\zMax, 
enlarge z limits={rel=0.25,upper},
xtick={1,...,10},
ytick={1,...,10},
%ytick={0,25,...,100},
grid=both,
xlabel={$x$},  ylabel={$y$},   zlabel={$z$},
minor z tick num=1,
point meta=explicit,
scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color!50!black, 
fill=mapped color!70},
]
% unitlenghth z-Axis determination 
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{   \pgfmathsetglobalmacro{\zunitlength}{\y1}   } node[xshift=2cm, yshift=2cm]{%\zunitlength % show value
}; 
\addplot3[
scatter, only marks,
mark=cube*, mark size=5,  %opacity=0.8,
nodes near coords*=, % will er...
%%% barheight determination 
visualization depends on={\thisrow{Z} \as \zvalue}, 
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\barheight}{\zunitlength*\zvalue},
/pgfplots/cube/size z=\barheight        
},
] table[x=X, y=Y,     
z expr={0.5*\thisrow{Z}}, 
meta expr={\thisrow{Y}}
]{\datatable}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```