# TikZ - Is it possibe to drape an image on face of a solid?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know one can write (and even [draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387496/project-an-image-in-a-surface-in-tikzpicture)) on a face of a solid following the perspective, like in

[image: writing with perspective]

obtained from this code that draws a fake (2-dim) representation of the cube:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=-0.5},yslant=-0.5]
  \shade[right color=gray!10, left color=black!50] (0,0) rectangle +(3,3);
  \node at (1.5,1.5) {\Huge 2};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5},yslant=0.5]
  \shade[right color=gray!70,left color=gray!10] (3,-3) rectangle +(3,3);
  \node at (4.5,-1.5) {\Huge 1};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1]
  \shade[bottom color=gray!10, top color=black!80] (6,3) rectangle +(-3,-3);
  \node at (4.5,1.5) {\Huge 3};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to drape an image like:

[image: world map wikipedia]

on top of, lets say, two faces of a cube?

I am aware of [draping on a plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58492/how-to-attach-a-2d-rectangular-image-to-a-3d-curved-surface-with-tikz-or-pstrick) but can't quite be applied here.

Comment: Couldn't you just `\includegraphics` the picture instead of a digit in your slanted node? It's just a matter of resizing and trimming than (which could be automated a bit surely}.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you elaborate on the possible solution? A simple use of ``\includegraphics`` would end up in an interminable hand ajustements of coordinates of the rectalgular image to fit the coordinates of the TikZ figure, just like the solution posted below.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, line join=bevel]
\node[draw, ultra thick, anchor=north east, yslant=-0.5] {\includegraphics[viewport={3.2cm 1.6cm 8.2cm 6.6cm}, clip]{example-image-a}};
\node[draw, ultra thick, anchor=north west, yslant=0.5] {\includegraphics[viewport={3.2cm 1.6cm 8.2cm 6.6cm}, clip]{example-image-b}};
\node[draw, ultra thick, anchor=south west, yslant=0.5, xslant=-1] {\includegraphics[viewport={3.2cm 1.6cm 8.2cm 6.6cm}, clip]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dice with image on the sides]

**Edit:**

With `tikz-3dplot` instead of manual `slant` you can change the view angles in `\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{110}`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, line join=bevel]
\node[draw, ultra thick, transform shape, canvas is yz plane at x=1] {\includegraphics[scale=0.4, viewport={3.2cm 1.6cm 8.2cm 6.6cm}, clip]{example-image-a}};
\node[draw, ultra thick, transform shape, canvas is xz plane at y=1] {\includegraphics[scale=0.4, viewport={3.2cm 1.6cm 8.2cm 6.6cm}, clip]{example-image-b}};
\node[draw, ultra thick, transform shape, canvas is xy plane at z=1] {\includegraphics[scale=0.4, viewport={3.2cm 1.6cm 8.2cm 6.6cm}, clip]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dice with images on sides]

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, line join=bevel]
\node[draw, thick, transform shape, canvas is yz plane at x=1]            {\adjustbox{trim={0.250\width} {0.333\height} {0.500\width} {0.333\height}, clip}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{ulvyP.png}}};
\node[draw, thick, transform shape, canvas is xz plane at y=1, xscale=-1] {\adjustbox{trim={0.500\width} {0.333\height} {0.250\width} {0.333\height}, clip}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{ulvyP.png}}};
\node[draw, thick, transform shape, canvas is xy plane at z=1, rotate=90] {\adjustbox{trim={0.250\width} {0.666\height} {0.500\width} {0.000\height}, clip}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{ulvyP.png}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cube with earth image on sides]

Image source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392282/why-does-cubemap-projection-preserve-lines-of-longitude-but-not-latitude

Comment: +1: Can you add some rational?

Comment: @hpekristiansen In this way one has to take care of the viewport, cropping, etc ... Can TikZ map tghe four corners of the image into the four corners of the quadrilateral?

Comment: What quadrilateral is that? I only see three rhombs(squares) and a hexagon. I do not know what mapping you mean.

Comment: The mapping from the square (or rectangle) with the image to the rhomb that makes up the image of the cube. If that mapping could be built in TikZ it would eliminate the need for controlling ``\includegraphics`` parameters.