# matlab2tikz and bar3 function

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab

If I use the function `hist3()` it perfectly works with `matlab2tikz`. But if I use
the function `bar3` I find this in my `matrix.tikz`:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.2.3.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2012, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
% 
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotset{compat=1.6}
\begin{axis}[%
view={-37.5}{30},
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.6, xmax=9.4,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
xmajorgrids,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
ymajorgrids,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
zmajorgrids,
axis lines*=left,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump,
unbounded coords=jump]

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,0.6,0)(0.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,1.6,0)(0.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,2.6,0)(0.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,3.6,0)(0.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,4.6,0)(0.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,5.6,0)(0.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,6.6,0)(0.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,7.6,0)(0.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,8.6,0)(0.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(0.6,0.6,0)(0.6,0.6,0.84)(0.6,1.4,0.84)(0.6,1.4,0)(0.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,1.6,0)(0.6,1.6,0.02)(0.6,2.4,0.02)(0.6,2.4,0)(0.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,2.6,0)(0.6,2.6,0.09)(0.6,3.4,0.09)(0.6,3.4,0)(0.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,3.6,0)(0.6,3.6,0.01)(0.6,4.4,0.01)(0.6,4.4,0)(0.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,4.6,0)(0.6,4.6,0)(0.6,5.4,0)(0.6,5.4,0)(0.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,5.6,0)(0.6,5.6,0.01)(0.6,6.4,0.01)(0.6,6.4,0)(0.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,6.6,0)(0.6,6.6,0.09)(0.6,7.4,0.09)(0.6,7.4,0)(0.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,7.6,0)(0.6,7.6,0.01)(0.6,8.4,0.01)(0.6,8.4,0)(0.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(0.6,8.6,0)(0.6,8.6,0.01)(0.6,9.4,0.01)(0.6,9.4,0)(0.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(1.4,0.6,0)(1.4,0.6,0.84)(1.4,1.4,0.84)(1.4,1.4,0)(1.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,1.6,0)(1.4,1.6,0.02)(1.4,2.4,0.02)(1.4,2.4,0)(1.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,2.6,0)(1.4,2.6,0.09)(1.4,3.4,0.09)(1.4,3.4,0)(1.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,3.6,0)(1.4,3.6,0.01)(1.4,4.4,0.01)(1.4,4.4,0)(1.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,4.6,0)(1.4,4.6,0)(1.4,5.4,0)(1.4,5.4,0)(1.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,5.6,0)(1.4,5.6,0.01)(1.4,6.4,0.01)(1.4,6.4,0)(1.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,6.6,0)(1.4,6.6,0.09)(1.4,7.4,0.09)(1.4,7.4,0)(1.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,7.6,0)(1.4,7.6,0.01)(1.4,8.4,0.01)(1.4,8.4,0)(1.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,8.6,0)(1.4,8.6,0.01)(1.4,9.4,0.01)(1.4,9.4,0)(1.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,0.6,0)(1.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,1.6,0)(1.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,2.6,0)(1.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,3.6,0)(1.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,4.6,0)(1.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,5.6,0)(1.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,6.6,0)(1.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,7.6,0)(1.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.4,8.6,0)(1.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,0.6,0)(1.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,1.6,0)(1.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,2.6,0)(1.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,3.6,0)(1.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,4.6,0)(1.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,5.6,0)(1.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,6.6,0)(1.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,7.6,0)(1.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,8.6,0)(1.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(1.6,0.6,0)(1.6,0.6,0.03)(1.6,1.4,0.03)(1.6,1.4,0)(1.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,1.6,0)(1.6,1.6,0.78)(1.6,2.4,0.78)(1.6,2.4,0)(1.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,2.6,0)(1.6,2.6,0.09)(1.6,3.4,0.09)(1.6,3.4,0)(1.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,3.6,0)(1.6,3.6,0.08)(1.6,4.4,0.08)(1.6,4.4,0)(1.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,4.6,0)(1.6,4.6,0.01)(1.6,5.4,0.01)(1.6,5.4,0)(1.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,5.6,0)(1.6,5.6,0.01)(1.6,6.4,0.01)(1.6,6.4,0)(1.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,6.6,0)(1.6,6.6,0.21)(1.6,7.4,0.21)(1.6,7.4,0)(1.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,7.6,0)(1.6,7.6,0.01)(1.6,8.4,0.01)(1.6,8.4,0)(1.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(1.6,8.6,0)(1.6,8.6,0.02)(1.6,9.4,0.02)(1.6,9.4,0)(1.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(2.4,0.6,0)(2.4,0.6,0.03)(2.4,1.4,0.03)(2.4,1.4,0)(2.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,1.6,0)(2.4,1.6,0.78)(2.4,2.4,0.78)(2.4,2.4,0)(2.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,2.6,0)(2.4,2.6,0.09)(2.4,3.4,0.09)(2.4,3.4,0)(2.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,3.6,0)(2.4,3.6,0.08)(2.4,4.4,0.08)(2.4,4.4,0)(2.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,4.6,0)(2.4,4.6,0.01)(2.4,5.4,0.01)(2.4,5.4,0)(2.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,5.6,0)(2.4,5.6,0.01)(2.4,6.4,0.01)(2.4,6.4,0)(2.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,6.6,0)(2.4,6.6,0.21)(2.4,7.4,0.21)(2.4,7.4,0)(2.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,7.6,0)(2.4,7.6,0.01)(2.4,8.4,0.01)(2.4,8.4,0)(2.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,8.6,0)(2.4,8.6,0.02)(2.4,9.4,0.02)(2.4,9.4,0)(2.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,0.6,0)(2.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,1.6,0)(2.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,2.6,0)(2.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,3.6,0)(2.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,4.6,0)(2.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,5.6,0)(2.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,6.6,0)(2.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,7.6,0)(2.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.4,8.6,0)(2.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,0.6,0)(2.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,1.6,0)(2.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,2.6,0)(2.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,3.6,0)(2.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,4.6,0)(2.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,5.6,0)(2.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,6.6,0)(2.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,7.6,0)(2.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,8.6,0)(2.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(2.6,0.6,0)(2.6,0.6,0.01)(2.6,1.4,0.01)(2.6,1.4,0)(2.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,1.6,0)(2.6,1.6,0)(2.6,2.4,0)(2.6,2.4,0)(2.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,2.6,0)(2.6,2.6,0.11)(2.6,3.4,0.11)(2.6,3.4,0)(2.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,3.6,0)(2.6,3.6,0.01)(2.6,4.4,0.01)(2.6,4.4,0)(2.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,4.6,0)(2.6,4.6,0)(2.6,5.4,0)(2.6,5.4,0)(2.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,5.6,0)(2.6,5.6,0)(2.6,6.4,0)(2.6,6.4,0)(2.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,6.6,0)(2.6,6.6,0.02)(2.6,7.4,0.02)(2.6,7.4,0)(2.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,7.6,0)(2.6,7.6,0)(2.6,8.4,0)(2.6,8.4,0)(2.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(2.6,8.6,0)(2.6,8.6,0.01)(2.6,9.4,0.01)(2.6,9.4,0)(2.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(3.4,0.6,0)(3.4,0.6,0.01)(3.4,1.4,0.01)(3.4,1.4,0)(3.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,1.6,0)(3.4,1.6,0)(3.4,2.4,0)(3.4,2.4,0)(3.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,2.6,0)(3.4,2.6,0.11)(3.4,3.4,0.11)(3.4,3.4,0)(3.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,3.6,0)(3.4,3.6,0.01)(3.4,4.4,0.01)(3.4,4.4,0)(3.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,4.6,0)(3.4,4.6,0)(3.4,5.4,0)(3.4,5.4,0)(3.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,5.6,0)(3.4,5.6,0)(3.4,6.4,0)(3.4,6.4,0)(3.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,6.6,0)(3.4,6.6,0.02)(3.4,7.4,0.02)(3.4,7.4,0)(3.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,7.6,0)(3.4,7.6,0)(3.4,8.4,0)(3.4,8.4,0)(3.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,8.6,0)(3.4,8.6,0.01)(3.4,9.4,0.01)(3.4,9.4,0)(3.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,0.6,0)(3.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,1.6,0)(3.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,2.6,0)(3.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,3.6,0)(3.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,4.6,0)(3.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,5.6,0)(3.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,6.6,0)(3.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,7.6,0)(3.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.4,8.6,0)(3.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,0.6,0)(3.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,1.6,0)(3.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,2.6,0)(3.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,3.6,0)(3.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,4.6,0)(3.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,5.6,0)(3.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,6.6,0)(3.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,7.6,0)(3.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,8.6,0)(3.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(3.6,0.6,0)(3.6,0.6,0.01)(3.6,1.4,0.01)(3.6,1.4,0)(3.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,1.6,0)(3.6,1.6,0.07)(3.6,2.4,0.07)(3.6,2.4,0)(3.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,2.6,0)(3.6,2.6,0.21)(3.6,3.4,0.21)(3.6,3.4,0)(3.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,3.6,0)(3.6,3.6,0.8)(3.6,4.4,0.8)(3.6,4.4,0)(3.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,4.6,0)(3.6,4.6,0)(3.6,5.4,0)(3.6,5.4,0)(3.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,5.6,0)(3.6,5.6,0.02)(3.6,6.4,0.02)(3.6,6.4,0)(3.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,6.6,0)(3.6,6.6,0.09)(3.6,7.4,0.09)(3.6,7.4,0)(3.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,7.6,0)(3.6,7.6,0.01)(3.6,8.4,0.01)(3.6,8.4,0)(3.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(3.6,8.6,0)(3.6,8.6,0.03)(3.6,9.4,0.03)(3.6,9.4,0)(3.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(4.4,0.6,0)(4.4,0.6,0.01)(4.4,1.4,0.01)(4.4,1.4,0)(4.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,1.6,0)(4.4,1.6,0.07)(4.4,2.4,0.07)(4.4,2.4,0)(4.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,2.6,0)(4.4,2.6,0.21)(4.4,3.4,0.21)(4.4,3.4,0)(4.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,3.6,0)(4.4,3.6,0.8)(4.4,4.4,0.8)(4.4,4.4,0)(4.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,4.6,0)(4.4,4.6,0)(4.4,5.4,0)(4.4,5.4,0)(4.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,5.6,0)(4.4,5.6,0.02)(4.4,6.4,0.02)(4.4,6.4,0)(4.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,6.6,0)(4.4,6.6,0.09)(4.4,7.4,0.09)(4.4,7.4,0)(4.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,7.6,0)(4.4,7.6,0.01)(4.4,8.4,0.01)(4.4,8.4,0)(4.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,8.6,0)(4.4,8.6,0.03)(4.4,9.4,0.03)(4.4,9.4,0)(4.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,0.6,0)(4.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,1.6,0)(4.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,2.6,0)(4.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,3.6,0)(4.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,4.6,0)(4.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,5.6,0)(4.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,6.6,0)(4.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,7.6,0)(4.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.4,8.6,0)(4.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,0.6,0)(4.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,1.6,0)(4.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,2.6,0)(4.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,3.6,0)(4.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,4.6,0)(4.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,5.6,0)(4.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,6.6,0)(4.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,7.6,0)(4.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,8.6,0)(4.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(4.6,0.6,0)(4.6,0.6,0.02)(4.6,1.4,0.02)(4.6,1.4,0)(4.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,1.6,0)(4.6,1.6,0.07)(4.6,2.4,0.07)(4.6,2.4,0)(4.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,2.6,0)(4.6,2.6,0.14)(4.6,3.4,0.14)(4.6,3.4,0)(4.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,3.6,0)(4.6,3.6,0.06)(4.6,4.4,0.06)(4.6,4.4,0)(4.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,4.6,0)(4.6,4.6,0.96)(4.6,5.4,0.96)(4.6,5.4,0)(4.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,5.6,0)(4.6,5.6,0.09)(4.6,6.4,0.09)(4.6,6.4,0)(4.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,6.6,0)(4.6,6.6,0.14)(4.6,7.4,0.14)(4.6,7.4,0)(4.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,7.6,0)(4.6,7.6,0.05)(4.6,8.4,0.05)(4.6,8.4,0)(4.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(4.6,8.6,0)(4.6,8.6,0.03)(4.6,9.4,0.03)(4.6,9.4,0)(4.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(5.4,0.6,0)(5.4,0.6,0.02)(5.4,1.4,0.02)(5.4,1.4,0)(5.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,1.6,0)(5.4,1.6,0.07)(5.4,2.4,0.07)(5.4,2.4,0)(5.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,2.6,0)(5.4,2.6,0.14)(5.4,3.4,0.14)(5.4,3.4,0)(5.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,3.6,0)(5.4,3.6,0.06)(5.4,4.4,0.06)(5.4,4.4,0)(5.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,4.6,0)(5.4,4.6,0.96)(5.4,5.4,0.96)(5.4,5.4,0)(5.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,5.6,0)(5.4,5.6,0.09)(5.4,6.4,0.09)(5.4,6.4,0)(5.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,6.6,0)(5.4,6.6,0.14)(5.4,7.4,0.14)(5.4,7.4,0)(5.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,7.6,0)(5.4,7.6,0.05)(5.4,8.4,0.05)(5.4,8.4,0)(5.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,8.6,0)(5.4,8.6,0.03)(5.4,9.4,0.03)(5.4,9.4,0)(5.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,0.6,0)(5.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,1.6,0)(5.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,2.6,0)(5.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,3.6,0)(5.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,4.6,0)(5.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,5.6,0)(5.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,6.6,0)(5.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,7.6,0)(5.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.4,8.6,0)(5.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,0.6,0)(5.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,1.6,0)(5.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,2.6,0)(5.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,3.6,0)(5.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,4.6,0)(5.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,5.6,0)(5.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,6.6,0)(5.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,7.6,0)(5.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,8.6,0)(5.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(5.6,0.6,0)(5.6,0.6,0.02)(5.6,1.4,0.02)(5.6,1.4,0)(5.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,1.6,0)(5.6,1.6,0.02)(5.6,2.4,0.02)(5.6,2.4,0)(5.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,2.6,0)(5.6,2.6,0.1)(5.6,3.4,0.1)(5.6,3.4,0)(5.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,3.6,0)(5.6,3.6,0.01)(5.6,4.4,0.01)(5.6,4.4,0)(5.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,4.6,0)(5.6,4.6,0.01)(5.6,5.4,0.01)(5.6,5.4,0)(5.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,5.6,0)(5.6,5.6,0.75)(5.6,6.4,0.75)(5.6,6.4,0)(5.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,6.6,0)(5.6,6.6,0.19)(5.6,7.4,0.19)(5.6,7.4,0)(5.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,7.6,0)(5.6,7.6,0.08)(5.6,8.4,0.08)(5.6,8.4,0)(5.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(5.6,8.6,0)(5.6,8.6,0.03)(5.6,9.4,0.03)(5.6,9.4,0)(5.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(6.4,0.6,0)(6.4,0.6,0.02)(6.4,1.4,0.02)(6.4,1.4,0)(6.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,1.6,0)(6.4,1.6,0.02)(6.4,2.4,0.02)(6.4,2.4,0)(6.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,2.6,0)(6.4,2.6,0.1)(6.4,3.4,0.1)(6.4,3.4,0)(6.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,3.6,0)(6.4,3.6,0.01)(6.4,4.4,0.01)(6.4,4.4,0)(6.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,4.6,0)(6.4,4.6,0.01)(6.4,5.4,0.01)(6.4,5.4,0)(6.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,5.6,0)(6.4,5.6,0.75)(6.4,6.4,0.75)(6.4,6.4,0)(6.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,6.6,0)(6.4,6.6,0.19)(6.4,7.4,0.19)(6.4,7.4,0)(6.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,7.6,0)(6.4,7.6,0.08)(6.4,8.4,0.08)(6.4,8.4,0)(6.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,8.6,0)(6.4,8.6,0.03)(6.4,9.4,0.03)(6.4,9.4,0)(6.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,0.6,0)(6.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,1.6,0)(6.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,2.6,0)(6.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,3.6,0)(6.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,4.6,0)(6.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,5.6,0)(6.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,6.6,0)(6.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,7.6,0)(6.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.4,8.6,0)(6.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,0.6,0)(6.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,1.6,0)(6.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,2.6,0)(6.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,3.6,0)(6.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,4.6,0)(6.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,5.6,0)(6.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,6.6,0)(6.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,7.6,0)(6.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,8.6,0)(6.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(6.6,0.6,0)(6.6,0.6,0.01)(6.6,1.4,0.01)(6.6,1.4,0)(6.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,1.6,0)(6.6,1.6,0.02)(6.6,2.4,0.02)(6.6,2.4,0)(6.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,2.6,0)(6.6,2.6,0.01)(6.6,3.4,0.01)(6.6,3.4,0)(6.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,3.6,0)(6.6,3.6,0)(6.6,4.4,0)(6.6,4.4,0)(6.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,4.6,0)(6.6,4.6,0)(6.6,5.4,0)(6.6,5.4,0)(6.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,5.6,0)(6.6,5.6,0.01)(6.6,6.4,0.01)(6.6,6.4,0)(6.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,6.6,0)(6.6,6.6,0.1)(6.6,7.4,0.1)(6.6,7.4,0)(6.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,7.6,0)(6.6,7.6,0.01)(6.6,8.4,0.01)(6.6,8.4,0)(6.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(6.6,8.6,0)(6.6,8.6,0.01)(6.6,9.4,0.01)(6.6,9.4,0)(6.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(7.4,0.6,0)(7.4,0.6,0.01)(7.4,1.4,0.01)(7.4,1.4,0)(7.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,1.6,0)(7.4,1.6,0.02)(7.4,2.4,0.02)(7.4,2.4,0)(7.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,2.6,0)(7.4,2.6,0.01)(7.4,3.4,0.01)(7.4,3.4,0)(7.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,3.6,0)(7.4,3.6,0)(7.4,4.4,0)(7.4,4.4,0)(7.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,4.6,0)(7.4,4.6,0)(7.4,5.4,0)(7.4,5.4,0)(7.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,5.6,0)(7.4,5.6,0.01)(7.4,6.4,0.01)(7.4,6.4,0)(7.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,6.6,0)(7.4,6.6,0.1)(7.4,7.4,0.1)(7.4,7.4,0)(7.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,7.6,0)(7.4,7.6,0.01)(7.4,8.4,0.01)(7.4,8.4,0)(7.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,8.6,0)(7.4,8.6,0.01)(7.4,9.4,0.01)(7.4,9.4,0)(7.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,0.6,0)(7.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,1.6,0)(7.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,2.6,0)(7.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,3.6,0)(7.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,4.6,0)(7.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,5.6,0)(7.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,6.6,0)(7.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,7.6,0)(7.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.4,8.6,0)(7.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,0.6,0)(7.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,1.6,0)(7.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,2.6,0)(7.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,3.6,0)(7.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,4.6,0)(7.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,5.6,0)(7.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,6.6,0)(7.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,7.6,0)(7.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,8.6,0)(7.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(7.6,0.6,0)(7.6,0.6,0.04)(7.6,1.4,0.04)(7.6,1.4,0)(7.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,1.6,0)(7.6,1.6,0.01)(7.6,2.4,0.01)(7.6,2.4,0)(7.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,2.6,0)(7.6,2.6,0.19)(7.6,3.4,0.19)(7.6,3.4,0)(7.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,3.6,0)(7.6,3.6,0.01)(7.6,4.4,0.01)(7.6,4.4,0)(7.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,4.6,0)(7.6,4.6,0.01)(7.6,5.4,0.01)(7.6,5.4,0)(7.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,5.6,0)(7.6,5.6,0.1)(7.6,6.4,0.1)(7.6,6.4,0)(7.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,6.6,0)(7.6,6.6,0.09)(7.6,7.4,0.09)(7.6,7.4,0)(7.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,7.6,0)(7.6,7.6,0.82)(7.6,8.4,0.82)(7.6,8.4,0)(7.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(7.6,8.6,0)(7.6,8.6,0.02)(7.6,9.4,0.02)(7.6,9.4,0)(7.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(8.4,0.6,0)(8.4,0.6,0.04)(8.4,1.4,0.04)(8.4,1.4,0)(8.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,1.6,0)(8.4,1.6,0.01)(8.4,2.4,0.01)(8.4,2.4,0)(8.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,2.6,0)(8.4,2.6,0.19)(8.4,3.4,0.19)(8.4,3.4,0)(8.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,3.6,0)(8.4,3.6,0.01)(8.4,4.4,0.01)(8.4,4.4,0)(8.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,4.6,0)(8.4,4.6,0.01)(8.4,5.4,0.01)(8.4,5.4,0)(8.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,5.6,0)(8.4,5.6,0.1)(8.4,6.4,0.1)(8.4,6.4,0)(8.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,6.6,0)(8.4,6.6,0.09)(8.4,7.4,0.09)(8.4,7.4,0)(8.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,7.6,0)(8.4,7.6,0.82)(8.4,8.4,0.82)(8.4,8.4,0)(8.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,8.6,0)(8.4,8.6,0.02)(8.4,9.4,0.02)(8.4,9.4,0)(8.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,0.6,0)(8.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,1.6,0)(8.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,2.6,0)(8.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,3.6,0)(8.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,4.6,0)(8.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,5.6,0)(8.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,6.6,0)(8.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,7.6,0)(8.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.4,8.6,0)(8.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,0.6,0)(8.6,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,1.6,0)(8.6,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,2.6,0)(8.6,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,3.6,0)(8.6,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,4.6,0)(8.6,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,5.6,0)(8.6,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,6.6,0)(8.6,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,7.6,0)(8.6,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,8.6,0)(8.6,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(8.6,0.6,0)(8.6,0.6,0.01)(8.6,1.4,0.01)(8.6,1.4,0)(8.6,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,1.6,0)(8.6,1.6,0.01)(8.6,2.4,0.01)(8.6,2.4,0)(8.6,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,2.6,0)(8.6,2.6,0.07)(8.6,3.4,0.07)(8.6,3.4,0)(8.6,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,3.6,0)(8.6,3.6,0.01)(8.6,4.4,0.01)(8.6,4.4,0)(8.6,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,4.6,0)(8.6,4.6,0)(8.6,5.4,0)(8.6,5.4,0)(8.6,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,5.6,0)(8.6,5.6,0.01)(8.6,6.4,0.01)(8.6,6.4,0)(8.6,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,6.6,0)(8.6,6.6,0.08)(8.6,7.4,0.08)(8.6,7.4,0)(8.6,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,7.6,0)(8.6,7.6,0.01)(8.6,8.4,0.01)(8.6,8.4,0)(8.6,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(8.6,8.6,0)(8.6,8.6,0.85)(8.6,9.4,0.85)(8.6,9.4,0)(8.6,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(9.4,0.6,0)(9.4,0.6,0.01)(9.4,1.4,0.01)(9.4,1.4,0)(9.4,0.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,1.6,0)(9.4,1.6,0.01)(9.4,2.4,0.01)(9.4,2.4,0)(9.4,1.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,2.6,0)(9.4,2.6,0.07)(9.4,3.4,0.07)(9.4,3.4,0)(9.4,2.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,3.6,0)(9.4,3.6,0.01)(9.4,4.4,0.01)(9.4,4.4,0)(9.4,3.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,4.6,0)(9.4,4.6,0)(9.4,5.4,0)(9.4,5.4,0)(9.4,4.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,5.6,0)(9.4,5.6,0.01)(9.4,6.4,0.01)(9.4,6.4,0)(9.4,5.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,6.6,0)(9.4,6.6,0.08)(9.4,7.4,0.08)(9.4,7.4,0)(9.4,6.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,7.6,0)(9.4,7.6,0.01)(9.4,8.4,0.01)(9.4,8.4,0)(9.4,7.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,8.6,0)(9.4,8.6,0.85)(9.4,9.4,0.85)(9.4,9.4,0)(9.4,8.6,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,0.6,0)(9.4,1.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,1.6,0)(9.4,2.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,2.6,0)(9.4,3.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,3.6,0)(9.4,4.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,4.6,0)(9.4,5.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,5.6,0)(9.4,6.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,6.6,0)(9.4,7.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,7.6,0)(9.4,8.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(9.4,8.6,0)(9.4,9.4,0)(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,(NaN,

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

And I can' t compile it with LaTeX. There is no error, all it says is `Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features)`.

All I initially wanted to do, is to represent a 9x9 Matrix with the help of a histogramm, to see which entrys are high...

I also found this: [3-dimensional histogram in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots) where anton explained how to do a Diagramm by yourself, but I don't understand why he uses triple like (NaN, NaN, 0 ) and there is also no nice colering solution...

EDIT: This is how my matlab code looks now (I think C has changed slightly)

```
function work_for_me_mr_pc()

C=[ 0.8445  0.0398  0.0069  0.0341  0.0199  0.0143  0.0109  0.0196  0.0099 
  0.0119  0.8153  0.0041  0.0057  0.0544  0.0086  0.0089  0.0847  0.0065 
  0.0852  0.1921  0.1077  0.0875  0.1365  0.2143  0.0102  0.0993  0.0671 
  0.0176  0.0135  0.004   0.7776  0.0693  0.0678  0.0203  0.0163  0.0136 
  0.0047  0.0129  0.0012  0.0055  0.9565  0.0045  0.0012  0.0135  0.     
  0.007   0.0118  0.008   0.0842  0.0572  0.8044  0.0038  0.0132  0.0102 
  0.0876  0.0878  0.0151  0.2129  0.1377  0.0905  0.095   0.1883  0.085  
  0.0109  0.0963  0.0046  0.0099  0.0867  0.0162  0.0092  0.7528  0.0134 
  0.0098  0.0164  0.0059  0.017   0.028   0.0319  0.0078  0.0304  0.8528];

bar3(C)
matlab2tikz( 'matrix.tikz' );
```

Comment: I don't think `bar3` is supported by matlab2tikz.

Comment: thats correct. What can I do when I need a plot of a 9x9 Matrix?

Comment: You can try `qtiplot` or `scidavis` and export it into tex.

Comment: Or you may try `matfig2pgf`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample matrix with its matlab code to generate the bar3 graph?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already mentioned that in my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*See update -2 about `plot2svg` at the bottom. This is the most suitable method for diagrams as complex as this one.*

This is not about a `9x9` matrix, but somewhat bigger than that. OK. After little try, I have this.

[image]

**How did I generate it?**

The actual figure is generated in matlab and the data points came as a result of some long computation. Then I generated the `pgf` code using [matfig2pgf](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12962). It converts the figure into low level `pgf` commands. Unlike `matlab2tikz` it also inserts a menu item in to the matlab figure window, making the life easier. The generated code is somewhat long, somewhat 18400 lines, (hence, not posting here.) This method involved lot of manual tweekings and **quite cumbersome.** Also it won't work consistently.

[image]

**Update:**

Here is another alternative using inkscape and [inkscape2tikz](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). First generate the figure in matlab, export it into pdf file. Now import this file into inkscape. In the pdf import settings window, *uncheck* Embed images:

[image]

Now export this into `tikz` using inkscape2tikz. It will generate the tex code (which again, is long, yuck!).

[image]

Here I have tweaked only the `line width` to be `1pt` in the `.tex` code (which was something like `4pt` and `2.667pt` earlier).

**Update-2**

Now using [plot2svg](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401)

I used `bar3(C,0.25,'detached');` in your matlab code to make things less cluttered.

Put `plot2svg.m` somewhere (mine is - C:\Users\myname\Documents\MATLAB). When the figure window is active in matlab, type `plot2svg` in command window. A UI will open asking for the save details. Save the figure as `.svg`. Now open it in inkscape, save it as `.tex` (tikz) file.

[image]

[image]

You can also include the `svg` directly using `svg` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[clean,pdf]{svg}
\begin{document}
  \includesvg[width=13cm]{work2}
\end{document}
```

Refer [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75039/11232) and [this answer by speravir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74693/11232) for details.

[image]

Comment: nice picture. Too bad that the code is so long.