# pgfplots: How to scale axis so that cubes stick together

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I have a *3D-*plot which produces

[image]

What is the correct way to scale the *x-axis and y-axis* so that the cubes *0,1,2,3* stick together? Something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
X,   Y,    Z
0,    0,   0
1,    0,   0
2,    0,   0
1,    -1,   0
4,    0,   0
}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%xmin=0, xmax=6, 
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1, 
grid=both,
point meta=explicit, % colors 1/2
xlabel={$x$},  ylabel={$y$},   zlabel={$z$},
% x=3mm, y=1cm, z=1cm, % not a good idea
]
\addplot3[scatter, mark=*, only marks,
mark=cube*, mark size=7,  
nodes near coords*=\coordindex,
] table [x=X, y=Y,z=Z,
meta expr={\thisrow{X}} % colors 2/2
] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457231/95441 help (as a workaround)?

Comment: Or what about https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots/54100#54100?

Comment: Ok, I think I can use 'enlarge the cubes dimensions' from your  1st suggestion ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457231/95441 )

Comment: Great to hear. So can we close your question as duplicate?