# 3D Histogram / bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, tikz-3dplot, histogram

Hello fellows and folks!

I wanted to know if it is possible to plot a 3D histogram like these: 
[image]

[image]

The file is a .csv one with 100K rows/tuples. My idea is to plot users (x-axis), movies(y-axis) and ratings (z-axis). For the first 10 rows or something like that.

Is it possible to draw?

This is how the structure of the file looks:

```
UserID, MovieID, Rating

1,5,5
2,4,3
3,4,2
4,2,2
5,3,5
6,1,5
7,2,2
8,2,3
9,1,4
1,2,4
1,3,4
2,2,3
2,3,5
2,5,4
3,1,5
3,2,2
3,5,3
4,3,3
4,4,1
4,5,2
5,1,4
5,4,4
5,5,5
6,2,3
6,4,3
6,5,5
7,1,3
7,3,3
7,4,2
8,1,5
8,3,4
8,5,5
9,2,2
9,3,5
9,4,4
10,3,5
10,4,3
10,5,4
```

Comment: Yes, it is, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435234/121799). Do you have the data in another form than a screen shot but just text?

Comment: Yes, I do! I will edit the post with the text data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a proposal. You need to compile twice.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102770/121799
\def\pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/iflessthan/.@cmd}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\pgfeov
}%
\def\pgfplotsmulticmpthree#1#2#3#4#5#6\do#7#8{%
    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#1}{#4}{%
        % first key <:
        #7%
    }{%
        \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#4}{#1}{%
            % first key >:
            #8%
        }{%
            % first key ==:
            \pgfplotsset{float <}%
            \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#2}{#5}{%
                % second key <
                #7%
            }{%
                \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#5}{#2}{%
                    % second key >
                    #8%
                }{%
                    % second key ==
                    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
                    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#3}{#6}{%
                        % third key <
                        #7%
                    }{%
                        % third key >=
                        #8%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\gconv
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gconv}{0.1}
\fi
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
y,x,myvalue
1,5,5
2,4,3
3,4,2
4,2,2
5,3,5
6,1,5
7,2,2
8,2,3
9,1,4
1,2,4
1,3,4
2,2,3
2,3,5
2,5,4
3,1,5
3,2,2
3,5,3
4,3,3
4,4,1
4,5,2
5,1,4
5,4,4
5,5,5
6,2,3
6,4,3
6,5,5
7,1,3
7,3,3
7,4,2
8,1,5
8,3,4
8,5,5
9,2,2
9,3,5
9,4,4
10,3,5
10,4,3
10,5,4
}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
        create col/assign/.code={%
            \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
        }
    },
    sort key=sortkey,
    sort cmp={%
        iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
            \edef\temp{#1#2}%
            \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
        },
    },
    sort,
    columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
    columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
        view={120}{40},
        width=320pt,
        height=280pt,
        z buffer=none,
        xmin=-1,xmax=5,
        ymin=0,ymax=9,
        zmin=0,zmax=10,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        ztick={0,5,10},
        zticklabels={0,2.5,5}, % here one has to "cheat"
        % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
        % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
        % values
        xtick=data,
        extra tick style={grid=major},
        ytick=data,
        grid=minor,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        zlabel={$z$},
        minor tick num=1,
        point meta=explicit,
        colormap name=viridis,
        scatter/use mapped color={
            draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
        execute at begin plot={}            
        ]
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
\ifx\gconv\conv
\else
\xdef\gconv{\conv}
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space the\space file!}
\fi     
        };  
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:1,0,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convx}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
\typeout{One\space unit\space in\space x\space 
        direction\space is\space\convx pt}
        };                  
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,1,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convy}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
\typeout{One\space unit\space in\space y\space 
        direction\space is\space\convy pt}
        };                  
\addplot3 [visualization depends on={
\gconv*z \as \myz}, % you may have to recompile to get the prefactor right
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=11.66135pt},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=9.10493pt},%
scatter,only marks,
mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
 table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
 expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
 meta expr={-1*\thisrow{x}}
        ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\gconv{\gconv}\relax}
\makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]