# 3D bar plot z axis size

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, bar-chart

I have seen 3D  bar plot code at [3D Histogram / bar chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491565/3d-histogram-bar-chart) but i cannot do it right for my data.
how to scale height of bars?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102770/121799
\def\pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/iflessthan/.@cmd}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\pgfeov
}%
\def\pgfplotsmulticmpthree#1#2#3#4#5#6\do#7#8{%
    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#1}{#4}{%
        % first key <:
        #7%
    }{%
        \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#4}{#1}{%
            % first key >:
            #8%
        }{%
            % first key ==:
            \pgfplotsset{float <}%
            \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#2}{#5}{%
                % second key <
                #7%
            }{%
                \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#5}{#2}{%
                    % second key >
                    #8%
                }{%
                    % second key ==
                    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
                    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#3}{#6}{%
                        % third key <
                        #7%
                    }{%
                        % third key >=
                        #8%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\gconv
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gconv}{0.1}
\fi
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
    y,x,myvalue

    1,1,45
    1,2,78
    1,3,100
    1,4,116
    2,1,37
    2,2,68
    2,3,94
    2,4,114
    3,1,28
    3,2,60
    3,3,90
    3,4,111
    4,1,26
    4,2,57
    4,3,87
    4,4,113


}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
},
sort key=sortkey,
sort cmp={%
    iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
        \edef\temp{#1#2}%
        \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
    },
},
sort,
columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}



    \begin{tikzpicture}%[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
    view={160}{30},
    width=320pt,
    height=280pt,
    z buffer=none,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    zmin=0,zmax=150,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    ztick={0,50,100,200},
    zticklabels={0,50,75,100}, % here one has to "cheat"
    % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
    % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
    % values
    xtick=data,
    extra tick style={grid=major},
    ytick=data,
    grid=minor,
    xlabel style={sloped},
    ylabel style={sloped},
    zlabel style={sloped},
    xlabel={
        {\scriptsize
            c}
    },
    ylabel={{\scriptsize
            b}},
    zlabel={{\scriptsize
            a
        }
    },
    minor tick num=1,
    point meta=explicit,
    colormap name=viridis,
    scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
    execute at begin plot={}            
    ]
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
        \ifx\gconv\conv
        \else
        \xdef\gconv{\conv}
        \typeout{Please\space recompile\space the\space file!}
        \fi     
    };  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:1,0,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convx}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space x\space 
            direction\space is\space\convx pt}
    };                  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,1,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convy}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space y\space 
            direction\space is\space\convy pt}
    };                  
    \addplot3 [visualization depends on={
        \gconv*z \as \myz}, % you may have to recompile to get the prefactor right
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=11.66135pt},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=9.10493pt},%
    scatter,only marks,
    mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
    table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
    expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
    meta expr={-1*\thisrow{x}}
    ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
    \makeatletter
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\gconv{\gconv}\relax}
    \makeatother
    \end{tikzpicture}





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only did not read the part where one has to cheat. You need to set the z labels to half the actual values because these bar plots are in reality just plot with cube marks (OK, these are cuboids, but pgfplots calls them cubes), which get stretched appropriately. That is, if we want an effective `zmax` of 120, and `zticklabels={0,30,60,90,120}`, we need to set

```
zmax=240,
ztick={0,60,120,180,240},
```

Doing that yields

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102770/121799
\def\pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/iflessthan/.@cmd}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\pgfeov
}%
\def\pgfplotsmulticmpthree#1#2#3#4#5#6\do#7#8{%
    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#1}{#4}{%
        % first key <:
        #7%
    }{%
        \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#4}{#1}{%
            % first key >:
            #8%
        }{%
            % first key ==:
            \pgfplotsset{float <}%
            \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#2}{#5}{%
                % second key <
                #7%
            }{%
                \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#5}{#2}{%
                    % second key >
                    #8%
                }{%
                    % second key ==
                    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
                    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#3}{#6}{%
                        % third key <
                        #7%
                    }{%
                        % third key >=
                        #8%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\gconv
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gconv}{0.1}
\fi
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
    y,x,myvalue

    1,1,45
    1,2,78
    1,3,100
    1,4,116
    2,1,37
    2,2,68
    2,3,94
    2,4,114
    3,1,28
    3,2,60
    3,3,90
    3,4,111
    4,1,26
    4,2,57
    4,3,87
    4,4,113


}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
},
sort key=sortkey,
sort cmp={%
    iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
        \edef\temp{#1#2}%
        \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
    },
},
sort,
columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}



    \begin{tikzpicture}%[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
    view={160}{30},
    width=320pt,
    height=280pt,
    z buffer=none,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    zmin=0,zmax=240,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    ztick={0,60,120,180,240},
    zticklabels={0,30,60,90,120}, % here one has to "cheat"
    % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
    % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
    % values
    xtick=data,
    extra tick style={grid=major},
    ytick=data,
    grid=minor,
    xlabel style={sloped},
    ylabel style={sloped},
    zlabel style={sloped},
    xlabel={
        {\scriptsize
            c}
    },
    ylabel={{\scriptsize
            b}},
    zlabel={{\scriptsize
            a
        }
    },
    minor tick num=1,
    point meta=explicit,
    colormap name=viridis,
    scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
    execute at begin plot={}            
    ]
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
        \ifx\gconv\conv
        \else
        \xdef\gconv{\conv}
        \typeout{Please\space recompile\space the\space file!}
        \fi     
    };  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:1,0,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convx}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space x\space 
            direction\space is\space\convx pt}
    };                  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,1,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convy}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space y\space 
            direction\space is\space\convy pt}
    };                  
    \addplot3 [visualization depends on={
        \gconv*z \as \myz}, % you may have to recompile to get the prefactor right
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=11.66135pt},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=9.10493pt},%
    scatter,only marks,
    mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
    table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
    expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
    meta expr={-1*\thisrow{x}}
    ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
    \makeatletter
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\gconv{\gconv}\relax}
    \makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the example from your comment:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102770/121799
\def\pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/iflessthan/.@cmd}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\pgfeov
}%
\def\pgfplotsmulticmpthree#1#2#3#4#5#6\do#7#8{%
    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#1}{#4}{%
        % first key <:
        #7%
    }{%
        \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#4}{#1}{%
            % first key >:
            #8%
        }{%
            % first key ==:
            \pgfplotsset{float <}%
            \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#2}{#5}{%
                % second key <
                #7%
            }{%
                \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#5}{#2}{%
                    % second key >
                    #8%
                }{%
                    % second key ==
                    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
                    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#3}{#6}{%
                        % third key <
                        #7%
                    }{%
                        % third key >=
                        #8%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\gconv
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gconv}{0.1}
\fi
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
    y,x,myvalue
    1,1,25
    1,2,16
    1,3,7
    1,4,3
    2,1,46
    2,2,29
    2,3,14
    2,4,5
    3,1,60
    3,2,38
    3,3,19
    3,4,8
    4,1,63
    4,2,43
    4,3,22
    4,4,7
}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
},
sort key=sortkey,
sort cmp={%
    iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
        \edef\temp{#1#2}%
        \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
    },
},
sort,
columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}



    \begin{tikzpicture}%[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
    view={160}{30},
    width=320pt,
    height=280pt,
    z buffer=none,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    zmin=0,zmax=140,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    ztick={0,20,60,100,140},
    zticklabels={0,10,30,50,70}, % here one has to "cheat"
    % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
    % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
    % values
    xtick=data,
    extra tick style={grid=major},
    ytick=data,
    grid=minor,
    xlabel style={sloped},
    ylabel style={sloped},
    zlabel style={sloped},
    xlabel={
        {\scriptsize
            c}
    },
    ylabel={{\scriptsize
            b}},
    zlabel={{\scriptsize
            a
        }
    },
    minor tick num=1,
    point meta=explicit,
    colormap name=viridis,
    scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
    execute at begin plot={}            
    ]
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
        \ifx\gconv\conv
        \else
        \xdef\gconv{\conv}
        \typeout{Please\space recompile\space the\space file!}
        \fi     
    };  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:1,0,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convx}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space x\space 
            direction\space is\space\convx pt}
    };                  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,1,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convy}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space y\space 
            direction\space is\space\convy pt}
    };                  
    \addplot3 [visualization depends on={
        \gconv*z \as \myz}, % you may have to recompile to get the prefactor right
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=11.66135pt},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=9.10493pt},%
    scatter,only marks,
    mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
    table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
    expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
    meta expr={-1*\thisrow{x}}
    ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
    \makeatletter
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\gconv{\gconv}\relax}
    \makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}r}
        \hline
        First Name & Text1 &\textbf{Some Company} \\
        &  email.com \\
        &  other info \\ \hline
        First Name & Text1 a awful lot longer that will nearly trigger a Carriage Return &  Some Company 2 \\ 
        &  email.com \\
          &  other info
        \\ \hline   
    \end{tabularx}
%\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for example for this data: y,x,myvalue
 1,1,25
 1,2,16
 1,3,7
 1,4,3
 2,1,46
 2,2,29
 2,3,14
 2,4,5
 3,1,60
 3,2,38
 3,3,19
 3,4,8
 4,1,63
 4,2,43
 4,3,22
 4,4,7///zmax=140,
ztick={0,20,60,100,140},zticklabels={0,10,30,50,70} // is right? but it doesnt complie right. meaning height is not right according to data.

Comment: @MahdiGholami I added the example from your comments to the answer. To me the bars look right.

Comment: thank you so much. its fine. I have another question:as you can see I have two plot like this and I want to address this in my document. I cannot. after first one, I copy the second, and both plot will in mess. i think because each code should run twice. what should I do.