# two 3-D barplot adjustment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, tikz-3dplot

I have two 3d bar plot like [3D bar plot z axis size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523027/3d-bar-plot-z-axis-size) and i want to include both in same .tex file.
each code should run twice for correct form, and because of that one cannot come after another. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you are using defines only one conversion factor `\gconv`. You need one per plot. The following does that. Please make sure that you say `\stepcounter{plotno}` for each new 3d bar plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcounter{plotno}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102770/121799
\def\pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan#1#2#3#4{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/iflessthan/.@cmd}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\pgfeov
}%
\def\pgfplotsmulticmpthree#1#2#3#4#5#6\do#7#8{%
    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#1}{#4}{%
        % first key <:
        #7%
    }{%
        \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#4}{#1}{%
            % first key >:
            #8%
        }{%
            % first key ==:
            \pgfplotsset{float <}%
            \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#2}{#5}{%
                % second key <
                #7%
            }{%
                \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#5}{#2}{%
                    % second key >
                    #8%
                }{%
                    % second key ==
                    \pgfplotsset{float <}%
                    \pgfplotsinvokeiflessthan{#3}{#6}{%
                        % third key <
                        #7%
                    }{%
                        % third key >=
                        #8%
                    }%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{plotno}{1}
\ifcsname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname
\else
\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname{0.1}
\fi
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
    y,x,myvalue
    1,1,25
    1,2,16
    1,3,7
    1,4,3
    2,1,46
    2,2,29
    2,3,14
    2,4,5
    3,1,60
    3,2,38
    3,3,19
    3,4,8
    4,1,63
    4,2,43
    4,3,22
    4,4,7
}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
},
sort key=sortkey,
sort cmp={%
    iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
        \edef\temp{#1#2}%
        \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
    },
},
sort,
columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}



    \begin{tikzpicture}%[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
    view={160}{30},
    width=320pt,
    height=280pt,
    z buffer=none,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    zmin=0,zmax=140,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    ztick={0,20,60,100,140},
    zticklabels={0,10,30,50,70}, % here one has to "cheat"
    % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
    % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
    % values
    xtick=data,
    extra tick style={grid=major},
    ytick=data,
    grid=minor,
    xlabel style={sloped},
    ylabel style={sloped},
    zlabel style={sloped},
    xlabel={
        {\scriptsize
            c}
    },
    ylabel={{\scriptsize
            b}},
    zlabel={{\scriptsize
            a
        }
    },
    minor tick num=1,
    point meta=explicit,
    colormap name=viridis,
    scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
    execute at begin plot={}            
    ]
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
        \expandafter\ifx\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname\conv
        \else
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname{\conv}
        \typeout{Please\space recompile\space the\space file!}
        \fi     
    };  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:1,0,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convx}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space x\space 
            direction\space is\space\convx pt}
    };                  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,1,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convy}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space y\space 
            direction\space is\space\convy pt}
    };                  
    \addplot3 [visualization depends on={
        \csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname*z \as \myz}, % you may have to recompile to get the prefactor right
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=11.66135pt},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=9.10493pt},%
    scatter,only marks,
    mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
    table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
    expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
    meta expr={-1*\thisrow{x}}
    ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
    \makeatletter
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\gconv\roman{plotno}{\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname}\relax}
    \makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}


\stepcounter{plotno}{1}\ifcsname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname
\else
\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname{0.1}
\fi
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{%
    y,x,myvalue
    1,1,45
    1,2,78
    1,3,100
    1,4,116
    2,1,37
    2,2,68
    2,3,94
    2,4,114
    3,1,28
    3,2,60
    3,3,90
    3,4,111
    4,1,26
    4,2,57
    4,3,87
    4,4,113
}{\datatable}
%
%\pgfplotstablesort[col sep=comma,header=true]\resulttable{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[create on use/sortkey/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry{{\thisrow{x}}{\thisrow{y}}{\thisrow{myvalue}}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
},
sort key=sortkey,
sort cmp={%
    iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
        \edef\temp{#1#2}%
        \expandafter\pgfplotsmulticmpthree\temp\do{#3}{#4}%
    },
},
sort,
columns/Mtx/.style={string type},
columns/Kind/.style={string type},]\resulttable{\datatable}



    \begin{tikzpicture}%[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]%[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)},z={(0cm,1 cm)}]
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
    view={160}{30},
    width=320pt,
    height=280pt,
    z buffer=none,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    zmin=0,zmax=240,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    ztick={0,60,120,180,240},
    zticklabels={0,30,60,90,120}, % here one has to "cheat"
    % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
    % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
    % values
    xtick=data,
    extra tick style={grid=major},
    ytick=data,
    grid=minor,
    xlabel style={sloped},
    ylabel style={sloped},
    zlabel style={sloped},
    xlabel={
        {\scriptsize
            c}
    },
    ylabel={{\scriptsize
            b}},
    zlabel={{\scriptsize
            a
        }
    },
    minor tick num=1,
    point meta=explicit,
    colormap name=viridis,
    scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
    execute at begin plot={}            
    ]
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
        \expandafter\ifx\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname\conv
        \else
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname{\conv}
        \typeout{Please\space recompile\space the\space file!}
        \fi     
    };  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:1,0,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convx}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space x\space 
            direction\space is\space\convx pt}
    };                  
    \path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,1,0)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\convy}{veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        \typeout{One\space unit\space in\space y\space 
            direction\space is\space\convy pt}
    };                  
    \addplot3 [visualization depends on={
        \csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname*z \as \myz}, % you may have to recompile to get the prefactor right
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=11.66135pt},%
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=9.10493pt},%
    scatter,only marks,
    mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
    table[x expr={\thisrow{x}},y expr={\thisrow{y}},z
    expr={1*\thisrow{myvalue}},
    meta expr={-1*\thisrow{x}}
    ] \resulttable;
    \end{axis}
    \makeatletter
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\gconv\roman{plotno}{\csname gconv\roman{plotno}\endcsname}\relax}
    \makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well done my friend. thanks a lot.