# Are the diagrams in James Stewart's Early Transcendentals made using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The book has a lot of beautiful vector diagrams like these.

[image]

[image]

I think pulling this off in TikZ is difficult so I was wondering whether TikZ was used, or some other software.

Comment: PSTricks can do this.

Comment: Figures 1 and 2 can be made rather easily with `pgfplots`.

Comment: The last two look like Maple.

Comment: If you have the book, look at the colophon, preface, acknowledgements etc. at the start of the book, there could be a note saying something about how the diagrams are made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that all of these figures can be produced with pgfplots. The histograms can be produces along the lines of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491566/194703), and the surfaces as parametric plots. Here is one example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[hide axis,view={50}{15},unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    colormap/viridis,
   declare function={R(\u)=0.5+\u/360;rr(\u)=0.05+\u/1080;
    torusx(\u,\v)=cos(\u)*(R(\u) + rr(\u)*cos(\v)); 
    torusy(\u,\v)=(R(\u) + rr(\u)*cos(\v))*sin(-1*\u);
    torusz(\u,\v)=rr(\u)*sin(\v);}]
  \addplot3[surf,point meta=rawx,%shader=interp,
    domain=0:720,domain y=0:360,samples=36,
    z buffer=sort] 
    ({torusx(x,y)},{torusy(x,y)},{torusz(x,y)-3*rr(x)});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[hide axis,view={50}{15},unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
  colormap/viridis,
   declare function={R(\u)=0.5+\u/360;rr(\u)=0.05+\u/1080;
    torusx(\u,\v)=cos(\u)*(R(\u) + rr(\u)*cos(\v)); 
    torusy(\u,\v)=(R(\u) + rr(\u)*cos(\v))*sin(-1*\u);
    torusz(\u,\v)=rr(\u)*sin(\v);}]
  \addplot3[surf,point meta=u,variable=u,variable y=v,%shader=interp,
    domain=0:720,domain y=0:360,samples=36,
    z buffer=sort] 
    ({torusx(u,v)},{torusy(u,v)},{torusz(u,v)-3*rr(u)});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]