# Plots used in Stewart's Calculus books

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to recreate some diagrams and graphs on Stewart's Calculus book. I've seen [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548170/are-the-diagrams-in-james-stewarts-early-transcendentals-made-using-tikz) but they didn't explain how to create the top left plot, the one I'm aiming to recreate. To begin with I'm trying this one

[image]

but all my attempts using TikZ have been miserably failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you a good starting point.  To plot the square root, I chose to plot x² against x instead of x against sqrt(x), because the precision of the square root calculation in TeX is not very good and also takes a long time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-1.3cm,-1.3cm)},y={(2.7cm,-.3cm)},z={(0cm,2cm)}]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[left] {$x$};
  \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
  \draw[->] (0,1,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[below] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[left] {$z$};
  \draw[thick,cyan] (0,0,0)
    -- plot[domain=0:1] ({\x*\x},{\x},{0})
    -- plot[domain=1:0] ({\x*\x},{\x},{1-\x});
  \fill[cyan,opacity=.2] (0,0,0)
    -- plot[domain=0:1] ({\x*\x},{\x},{0})
    -- plot[domain=1:0] ({\x*\x},{\x},{1-\x});
    -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,cyan] (0,0,1)
    -- plot[domain=0:1] ({\x*\x},{\x},{1-\x})
    -- (0,1,0)
    -- cycle;
  \fill[cyan,opacity=.2] (0,0,1)
    -- plot[domain=0:1] ({\x*\x},{\x},{1-\x})
    -- (0,1,0)
    -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That’s amazing!! I’ll try to work my way around your code for other graphs. Thank you so much!