# Drawing with 2 parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

Some days ago I posted [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656574/plots-used-in-stewarts-calculus-books). The code suggested really helped me to draw some nice curves and surfaces just like I wanted, but when it came to surfaces that depended on two variables/parameters I couldn't get the code to work. For example, I'm trying to do something like this

[image]

and so I started trying to plot just the surface of one sphere. I read a lot of topics on this and it always seems to use some parameter definition using pgf, but I found a code using just TikZ that I kinda liked and tried adapting to my use case.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-1.3cm,-1.3cm)},y={(2.7cm,-.3cm)},z={(0cm,2cm)}, scale=0.3, > = Straight Barb]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[left] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[below] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[left] {$z$};
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0, 1/1, ..., 10/10}
{
  \draw[->, ultra thick, red] ({\x}, {\y}, {(1 - {\x}**2 - {\y}**2)**(1/2)}) ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I put some random values for the variables just to test, but it's returning me an error

> Missing number, treated as zero

I've tried changing `({\x}, {\y}, {(1 - {\x}**2 - {\y}**2)**(1/2)})` to `({\x}, {\y}, {(1 - \x**2 - \y**2)**(1/2)})` but I couldn't get rid of the error. Then I started thinking of doing something with pgf using another coordinate system, but I'm really stuck and don't know what to do and I came again to ask for help. If anyone can explain how I would get something like the image I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Does the loop even work? I doubt the `...` syntax can deal with `/`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I got that from another question I saw on this topic so I suppose it works

Comment: it can't really work, what would you expect `0/0,...,5/9` to do?  also please post a test document not just a fragment

Comment: If you're talking about my question, I specifically said it doesn't work ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to draw spheres using isometric perspective. For example, with the `isometric view` form `perspective` Ti*k*Z library. With that and `3d` library for the `canvas is...` options yo con draw something like this:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\tikzset
{
  axis/.style={black,-latex},
  xy/.style={canvas is xy plane at z=0},
  xz/.style={canvas is xz plane at y=0},
  yz/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=0},
}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=180,blue]
  % sphere, inside
  \draw[xy,fill=blue!60] (2,0) arc (0:-270:2) -- (0,1) arc (90:360:1) -- cycle;
  % sphere, outside
  \draw[shading=ball,ball color=blue!60] 
        {[xy] (2,0) arc (0:-45:2)} arc (180:0:2 cm) 
        {[xy] arc (135:90:2)} -- (0,0,2) -- cycle;
  % slices
  \draw  [xz,fill=blue!20] (1,0) -- (2,0) arc (0:90:2) -- (0,1) arc (90:0:1) -- cycle;
  \draw  [yz,fill=blue!30] (1,0) -- (2,0) arc (0:90:2) -- (0,1) arc (90:0:1) -- cycle;
  % axes
  \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[left]  {\strut$x$};
  \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[right] {\strut$y$};
  \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do it for drawing a paraboloid?

Comment: @TulioAlves, a paraboloid wont be so easy but it can be done. Perhaps pgfplots or asymptote could be a better tool in this case. However, take a look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619390/how-can-i-draw-the-surface-fx-y-x2y2-like-my-picture/619495