# 3D stacked bar histogram with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, tikz-3dplot, histogram

I would like to plot a 3D stacked histogram like this (generated with Excel) with pgfplots:

[image]

The data are as follows:

```
Category    Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
Cat1        20      23      13      14      30
Cat2        18      10      20      22      30
Cat3        16      17      16      20      21
Cat4        13      19      19      14      35
Cat5        10      25      23      12      20
Cat6        24      20      12      19      25
Cat7        14      25      20      24      17
Cat8        24      25      19      10      22
Cat9        24      17      18      14      27
```

Is it possible to draw?

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491565/3d-histogram-bar-chart?rq=1 . (Once you posted your question, you'll often find useful links to the right under "Related".)