# Isometric Elevation Grid in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

Is there a (simplistic?) way to draw a 3D elevation grid like this in Tikz or PGFPlots?

[image: 3D Elevation Grid]

The blue line should be able to move up or down and, eventually, submerge the interior blocks.

I've looked at [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/plane-partition/), and follow it well enough that I could probably reconstruct things on my own, but it seems like at least some part of this may already exist as a package.

I would also be willing to use packages aside from TikZ or PGFPlots.

Comment: Does this come close to what you want? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots

Comment: Yes, that's looking close, @percusse. Now, if the tops or entirety of the histogram bars could be individually coloured...

Answer (score 18):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{37,111,197}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{211,200,134}

\def\rOne{0.75}
\def\rTwo{0.75}
\def\tOne{30}
\def\tTwo{-5}
\def\stripH{0.5}

\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    fillstyle=solid,
    linejoin=1,
}

\def\Bar(#1,#2)#3{%
    \rput(!#2 \rTwo\space mul \tTwo\space PtoC){%
        \rput(!#1 \rOne\space mul \tOne\space 180 add PtoC){%
            \pstGeonode{O}(\rOne;\tOne){One}(\rTwo;\tTwo){Two}
            \pstTranslation{O}{Two}{One}[Three]
            \pnode(0,\stripH){O'}
            \pstTranslation{O}{O'}{One,Two,Three}
            \pnode(0,#3){O''}
            \pstTranslation{O'}{O''}{One',Two',Three'}
            \psset{fillcolor=myblue}
                \pspolygon(O')(O)(Two)(Two')
                \pspolygon(Two')(Two)(Three)(Three')
            \psset{fillcolor=mybrown}
                \pspolygon(O'')(O')(Two')(Two'')
                \pspolygon(Two'')(Two')(Three')(Three'')
                \pspolygon(One'')(O'')(Two'')(Three'')
        }%
    }%
}

\newcount\OuterIndex
\def\SaveListContents#1\relax{\def\Contents{#1}}

\def\Picture{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-2)(5,4)
    \psforeach{\row}{%
        {{3,2.8,2.7,3,3.1}},% <=== Only this row must use double curly braces. It is a feature!
        {2.8,1,1.2,2,3},%
        {2.8,1,1.2,2,2.8},%
        {2.6,1.6,1.8,1.9,1.8},%
        {2.4,1.5,1.7,1.9,1.5}%
    }{%
        \expandafter\SaveListContents\row\relax
        \OuterIndex=\psLoopIndex\relax
        \psforeach{\col}{\Contents}{\Bar(\the\OuterIndex,\the\psLoopIndex){\col}}%
        \psLoopIndex=\OuterIndex\relax
    }
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\Picture
\end{document}
```

### Animation 1

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{37,111,197}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{211,200,134}

\def\rOne{0.75}
\def\rTwo{0.75}
\def\tOne{30}
\def\tTwo{-15}
\def\stripH{0.5}

\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    fillstyle=solid,
    linejoin=1,
}

\def\RandomBar(#1,#2){%
    \rput(!#2 \rTwo\space mul \tTwo\space PtoC){%
        \rput(!#1 \rOne\space mul \tOne\space 180 add PtoC){%
            \pstGeonode{O}(\rOne;\tOne){One}(\rTwo;\tTwo){Two}
            \pstTranslation{O}{Two}{One}[Three]
            \pnode(0,\stripH){O'}
            \pstTranslation{O}{O'}{One,Two,Three}
            \pnode(!0 rand 201 mod 100 div 1.00 add){O''}
            \pstTranslation{O'}{O''}{One',Two',Three'}
            \psset{fillcolor=myblue}
                \pspolygon(O')(O)(Two)(Two')
                \pspolygon(Two')(Two)(Three)(Three')
            \psset{fillcolor=mybrown}
                \pspolygon(O'')(O')(Two')(Two'')
                \pspolygon(Two'')(Two')(Three')(Three'')
                \pspolygon(One'')(O'')(Two'')(Three'')
        }%
    }%
}

\newcount\OuterIndex
\def\SaveListContents#1\relax{\def\Contents{#1}}

\def\Picture{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.5,-3)(4.25,2.5)
    \psforeach{\row}{1,2,..,5}{\psforeach{\col}{1,2,..,5}{\RandomBar(\row,\col)}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{20}{\Picture}
\end{document}
```

### Animation 2

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{37,111,197}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{211,200,134}

\def\rOne{0.75}
\def\rTwo{0.75}
\def\tOne{30}
\def\tTwo{-15}
\def\stripH{0.5}

\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    fillstyle=solid,
    linejoin=1,
}

\def\RandomBar(#1,#2){%
    \rput(!#2 \rTwo\space mul \tTwo\space PtoC){%
        \rput(!#1 \rOne\space mul \tOne\space 180 add PtoC){%
            \pstGeonode{O}(\rOne;\tOne){One}(\rTwo;\tTwo){Two}
            \pstTranslation{O}{Two}{One}[Three]
            \pnode(0,\stripH){O'}
            \pstTranslation{O}{O'}{One,Two,Three}
            \pnode(!0 rand 201 mod 100 div 1.00 add){O''}
            \pstTranslation{O'}{O''}{One',Two',Three'}
            \psset{fillcolor=myblue}
                \pspolygon(O')(O)(Two)(Two')
                \pspolygon(Two')(Two)(Three)(Three')
            \psset{fillcolor=mybrown}
                \pspolygon(O'')(O')(Two')(Two'')
                \pspolygon(Two'')(Two')(Three')(Three'')
                \pspolygon(One'')(O'')(Two'')(Three'')
        }%
    }%
}

\newcount\OuterIndex
\def\SaveListContents#1\relax{\def\Contents{#1}}

\def\Picture{\psforeach{\row}{1,2,..,5}{\psforeach{\col}{1,2,..,5}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.5,-3)(4.25,2.5)
    \RandomBar(\row,\col)
\end{pspicture}}}}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{1}{\Picture}
\end{document}
```

### Animation 3

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{37,111,197}
\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{211,200,134}

\def\rOne{0.75}
\def\rTwo{0.75}
\def\tOne{20}
\def\tTwo{-45}
\FPset\RowMaxIndex{4}% because zero based index
\FPset\ColMaxIndex{4}% because zero based index


\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    fillstyle=solid,
    linejoin=1,
}

\def\Bar(#1,#2)#3{%
    \rput(!#2 \rTwo\space mul \tTwo\space PtoC){%
        \rput(!#1 \rOne\space mul \tOne\space 180 add PtoC){%
            \pstGeonode{O}(\rOne;\tOne){One}(\rTwo;\tTwo){Two}
            \pstTranslation{O}{Two}{One}[Three]
            \pnode(0,\stripH){O'}
            \pstTranslation{O}{O'}{One,Two,Three}
            \pnode(0,#3){O''}
            \pstTranslation{O}{O''}{One,Two,Three}[One'',Two'',Three'']
            \psset{fillcolor=mybrown}
            \pspolygon(O'')(O)(Two)(Two'')
            \pspolygon(Two'')(Two)(Three)(Three'')
            \pspolygon(One'')(O'')(Two'')(Three'')
            \psset{fillcolor=myblue,opacity=0.75,linestyle=none,linewidth=0}
            \FPifeq{#1}{\RowMaxIndex}\pspolygon(O')(O)(Two)(Two')\fi
            \FPifeq{#2}{\ColMaxIndex}\pspolygon(Two')(Two)(Three)(Three')\fi
            \FPiflt{#3}{\stripH}\pspolygon(One')(O')(Two')(Three')\fi
        }%
    }%
}

\newcount\OuterIndex
\def\SaveListContents#1\relax{\def\Contents{#1}}

\def\Picture#1{%
\def\stripH{#1}%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.5,-3.35)(3.05,3.05)
    \psforeach{\row}{%
        {{3,2.8,2.7,3,3.1}},% <=== Only this row must use double curly braces. It is a feature!
        {2.8,1,1.2,2,3},%
        {2.8,1,1.2,2,2.8},%
        {2.6,1.6,1.8,1.9,1.8},%
        {2.4,1.5,1.7,1.9,1.5}%
    }{%
        \expandafter\SaveListContents\row\relax
        \OuterIndex=\psLoopIndex\relax
        \psforeach{\col}{\Contents}{\Bar(\the\OuterIndex,\the\psLoopIndex){\col}}%
        \psLoopIndex=\OuterIndex\relax
    }
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.0+0.2}{17}{\Picture{\n}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does your animation look like an earthquake, 
while the question clearly is more related to flood simulation?

Comment: @g.kov: Because I have not read the question description yet. I am a visual learner and only saw the given diagram. It is my bad!

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm fine with having an earthquake :-) But I wonder, could you explain how to change the viewing perspective? Or is that hard-coded?

Comment: @Richard: you can try modifying `\aTwo` and `\aOne`.

Comment: Your demo is very eye-catching but it's not clear if the blocks get drawn properly if they're submerged. It would be nice if you could change your demo to show what happens when the blocks are submerged. Personally, I'd prefer a still picture because that would give me time to study the picture.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: The requested animation has been added to my answer.

Comment: @g.kov: See my animation, does it still like an earthquake?

Comment: Another question, @Karl'sstudents. I've tried to compile all of your examples, but always get: `Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps`. Any thoughts as to why? I am using TeXLive 2012.

Comment: @Richard: You have to use either `xelatex` (slower) or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence (faster).

Answer (score 13):

My take:

[image: graph]

## How I did it

Since tikz is not well suited for this kind of graphic (which has to find intersections between planes, decomposing the figure in sub-objects and draw them in the correct order so that the nearest one hide the farthest ones) I used [`sketch`](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/), which can do these things and produce tikz code as result.

Next is the `skecth` code. The grid is a 5x5x5 cube. The water level is a real between 0 and 5. As for the height of each prism, unfortunately `sketch` does not provide primitives for reading numbers from files, nor to do list or array manipulation, so I had to draw each bar "one by one", instead of using a loop, and "hardcoded" their height in each case (the second number in the `scale` operation) :-(

```
def water_level 2.3 

def prism {
  sweep[fill style=prism]
  { 4<>, rotate(360/4,[0,1,0]) }
  line[fill style=prism](0.5,0,0.5)(0.5,1,0.5)
}

def water {
  sweep[fill style=water]
  { 4<>, rotate(360/4,[0,1,0]) }
  line[fill style=water, style=water](2.52,0,2.52)(2.52, 1, 2.52)
}


def grid {
  put { translate([0, 0, 0]) then scale([1,   5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([1, 0, 0]) then scale([1, 4.5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([2, 0, 0]) then scale([1, 4.3, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([3, 0, 0]) then scale([1, 4.8, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([4, 0, 0]) then scale([1,   5, 1])}{ {prism} }

  put { translate([0, 0, 1]) then scale([1, 4.5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([1, 0, 1]) then scale([1,   2, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([2, 0, 1]) then scale([1, 2.2, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([3, 0, 1]) then scale([1,   4, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([4, 0, 1]) then scale([1, 4.9, 1])}{ {prism} }

  put { translate([0, 0, 2]) then scale([1, 4.5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([1, 0, 2]) then scale([1,   2, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([2, 0, 2]) then scale([1, 2.2, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([3, 0, 2]) then scale([1,   4, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([4, 0, 2]) then scale([1, 4.5, 1])}{ {prism} }

  put { translate([0, 0, 3]) then scale([1, 4.0, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([1, 0, 3]) then scale([1, 3.0, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([2, 0, 3]) then scale([1, 3.2, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([3, 0, 3]) then scale([1, 3.5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([4, 0, 3]) then scale([1, 3.0, 1])}{ {prism} }

  put { translate([0, 0, 4]) then scale([1, 3.5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([1, 0, 4]) then scale([1, 2.8, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([2, 0, 4]) then scale([1, 3.0, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([3, 0, 4]) then scale([1, 3.5, 1])}{ {prism} }
  put { translate([4, 0, 4]) then scale([1, 2.5, 1])}{ {prism} }

  put { translate([2, 0, 2]) then scale([1, water_level, 1])}{ {water} }
}

put{ view((10,20,20)) }{{grid}}  % Draw it!

global { language tikz }
```

You save this code in a file named `elevation-grid.sketch` and compile it with:

```
$ sketch elevation-grid.sketch > tikzpicture.tex
```

Then, your main `elevation-grid.tex` document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  prism/.style = {draw=black, fill=black!30, opacity=1},
  water/.style = {draw=black, fill=blue, opacity=0.60},
}
\begin{document}
\input{tikzpicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

Of course this generates the graphic for a paticular water level (2.8 in the example). To generate the animation, you have to repeat the above a lot of times, for different `water_level` values. In order to automate this process, I removed the `water_level` definition from the first line of `elevation-grid.sketch` and wrote this small shell script (it requires `convert` utility from Imagemagick):

```
echo "def water_level $1" > aux.sketch
cat elevation-grid.sketch >> aux.sketch
sketch aux.sketch > tikzpicture.tex
pdflatex elevation-grid.tex
convert -density 300 elevation-grid.pdf elevation-grid-$1.png
```

If you save this code in a file named `run`, for example, you may call it with:

```
$ sh run 1.2
$ sh run 1.3
$ sh run 1.4
etc...
```

and you'll get a set of png files: `elevation-grid-1.2.png`, `elevation-grid-1.3.png`, and so on. Of course I also automated the above to generate values between 1.0 and 3.9. When all `png` figures were finally generated, I converted them to an animated gif with `convert` again:

```
$ convert -delay 20 elevation-grid*png animation.gif
```

## Update

[image: Big city]

Now the `sketch` script is generated by a python script. Currently the data for the grid
is randomly generated, but it would be trivial to read it from a file. This is the script:

```python
import random

def randomGrid(x,y,z):
    grid = []
    for i in range(y):
        row = []
        for j in range(x):
            row.append(random.random()*z+1)
        grid.append(row)
    return grid

def generateGraphic(grid, water_level):
    code = []
    code.append("def grid {")
    y = 0
    for row in grid:
        x = 0
        for cell in row:
            code.append("  put { translate([%d, 0, %d]) then scale([1,   %f, 1])}{ {prism} }" %                         (x, y, cell))
            x = x + 1
        code.append("")
        y = y + 1
    code.append("put { scale([%f, %f, %f]) then  translate([%f, 0, %f])}{ {water} }" %                 (x+0.01, water_level, y+0.01, x/2.0-0.5, y/2.0-0.5))
    code.append("}")
    return "\n".join(code)

def preamble():
    return """
def prism {
  sweep[fill style=prism]
  { 4<>, rotate(360/4,[0,1,0]) }
  line[fill style=prism](0.5,0,0.5)(0.5,1,0.5)
}

def water {
  sweep[fill style=water]
  { 4<>, rotate(360/4,[0,1,0]) }
  line[fill style=water, style=water](0.5,0,0.5)(0.5, 1, 0.5)
}
    """

def final(camera):
    return """put{ view((%f,%f,%f)) }{{grid}}  %% Draw it!
            global { language tikz }""" % camera

g = randomGrid(20,20,7)  % 20x20 cells, max height =7
print preamble()
print generateGraphic(g, 4.2)  % 4.2 is the water level
print final(camera=(30,60,60)) % 3D position of camera, looking at origin
```

To be used like this:

```
$ python generate-sketch.py > elevation-grid.sketch
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the PDF output to GIF directly (without via PNG)?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents because I'm not generating a multi-page pdf, but a single pdf for each run. Yes, I could improve that.. but it was only a proof-of-concept.

Comment: It is too bad about the lack of loops and arrays, @JLDiaz, because this solution is otherwise _so_ clean.

Comment: @Richard Note that the sketch program which generates the figure, can be in turn generated by another program. I updated my answer to include a python script which generates the sketch code.

Comment: @JLDiaz. Sketch is looking like the best way to do this, but I'm hitting a problem; not sure what a good forum for it is. I thought I'd spill the water into the middle of the elevations through the lower topography on the left-hand side. [This](http://justpaste.it/29iy) script is generating [this](http://imgur.com/fBS1yWl) image, but why does the water polygon bleed through the prisms?

Comment: @Richard Looks like some kind of bug in sketch. It does not like swepts of non-convex polygons (they confuse the algorithm wich decides the z-index order). You can build your L-shaped water with two rectangular blocks, and [this works well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1YzJy.png).

Comment: Thanks, @JLDiaz, it is nice to know I'm not crazy. The two-block idea will leave a visible joint as the L rises, though :-/

Comment: @Richard  you are right, but I cannot imagine a solution for this, except that when the water rises enough to the joint be visible, then use your L-shaped polygon again. Presumibly the problem for lower water levels will not appear for higher water levels, because now the "top cover" of the water does not intersects so many columns.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to TikZ or PGFPlots: Asymptote (part of TeXLive2012):

[image]

Source file `wdem.asy`:

```
size(6cm,0);
int frameNo;
usersetting(); // set frameNo from commandline 
real[][] dem={
{3,4,7,7.5,8},
{5,5,6,6,7.5},
{4.3,4.4,3.9,4.1,6},
{4.7,4.75,2.2,2.3,6.5},
{5,6,6.2,6.2,7.3},
{4.85,7,5.2,6.1,7.2},
};

import bsp;
real u=2.5;
real v=1;
currentprojection=oblique;
path3[] bar={
  plane((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,0)),
  plane((0,1,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,0)),
  plane((1,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,0)),
  plane((-1,0,0),(0,-1,0),(1,1,1)),
  plane((0,-1,0),(0,0,-1),(1,1,1)),
  plane((-1,0,0),(0,0,-1),(1,1,1)),
};  
face[] faces;

int nz=dem[0].length;
int nx=dem.length;

void barPlot(real wl){
  transform3 t;
  real peak;
  for(int i=0;i<nx;++i){ 
    for(int j=0;j<nz;++j){ 
      peak=dem[nx-1-i][nz-1-j];
      if(peak>0){
        t=shift(i,0,j)*scale(1-1e-3,peak,1-1e-3);
        for(int k=0;k<bar.length;++k){ 
          filldraw(faces.push(t*bar[k]),project(t*bar[k]),lightgreen);//+opacity(0.5));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  t=shift(1e-3,0,1e-3)*scale(nx+1e-3,wl,nz+1e-3); 
  for(int k=0;k<bar.length;++k){ 
    filldraw(faces.push(t*bar[k]),project(t*bar[k]),blue+opacity(0.5));
  }
  add(faces);
}

real wlNow;
real wlLow=3.8;
real wlHigh=6.3;
int frames=30; 
assert(frames>1,"At least two frames is a must.");
real dt=1.0/(frames-1);
real t=frameNo*dt;

wlNow=wlLow*(1-t)+wlHigh*t;
barPlot(wlNow);
shipout(format("f%02i",frameNo));
```

Frames were processed with batch file `gen-anim.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
frames=30
for((i=0;i<${frames};++i)){
  echo "Frame $i begin"
  asy -noV -tex=none -f pdf -noprc -u frameNo="$i" wdem.asy
  echo "Frame $i end"
}
```

An animation was created from 30 pdf frames 
by `convert -colors 32 -density 200 -antialias -delay 20 f*pdf fdem0.gif` and
optimized with `gifsicle --colors 16 --resize 236x_ -O3 <fdem0.gif >fdem.gif`.

**Edit**: version with individually coloured bars:

```
size(6cm,0);
int frameNo;
usersetting(); // set frameNo from commandline 
real[][] dem={
{3,4,7,7.5,8},
{5,5,6,6,7.5},
{4.3,4.4,3.9,4.1,6},
{4.7,4.75,2.2,2.3,6.5},
{5,6,6.2,6.2,7.3},
{4.85,7,5.2,6.1,7.2},
};

int nz=dem[0].length;
int nx=dem.length;

pen[][] demColor=new pen[nx][nz];

srand(56091);
for(int i=0;i<nx;++i){ 
  for(int j=0;j<nz;++j){ 
    demColor[i][j]=rgb(unitrand(),unitrand(),unitrand());
  }
}


import bsp;
real u=2.5;
real v=1;
currentprojection=oblique;
path3[] bar={
  plane((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,0)),
  plane((0,1,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,0)),
  plane((1,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,0)),
  plane((-1,0,0),(0,-1,0),(1,1,1)),
  plane((0,-1,0),(0,0,-1),(1,1,1)),
  plane((-1,0,0),(0,0,-1),(1,1,1)),
};  
face[] faces;


void barPlot(real wl){
  transform3 t;
  real peak;
  for(int i=0;i<nx;++i){ 
    for(int j=0;j<nz;++j){ 
      peak=dem[nx-1-i][nz-1-j];
      if(peak>0){
        t=shift(i,0,j)*scale(1-1e-3,peak,1-1e-3);
        for(int k=0;k<bar.length;++k){ 
          filldraw(faces.push(t*bar[k]),project(t*bar[k]),demColor[nx-1-i][nz-1-j]);//+opacity(0.5));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  t=shift(1e-3,0,1e-3)*scale(nx+1e-3,wl,nz+1e-3); 
  for(int k=0;k<bar.length;++k){ 
    filldraw(faces.push(t*bar[k]),project(t*bar[k]),blue+opacity(0.5));
  }
  add(faces);
}

real wlNow;
real wlLow=3.8;
real wlHigh=6.3;
int frames=30; 
assert(frames>1,"At least two frames is a must.");
real dt=1.0/(frames-1);
real t=frameNo*dt;

wlNow=wlLow*(1-t)+wlHigh*t;
barPlot(wlNow);
shipout(format("f%02i",frameNo));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @g.kov. Sadly, this compiles _extremely_ slowly on my otherwise zippy computer. Any thoughts on how to speed up the process?