# Very fancy bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

Just wonder if this could be done with tikz? I know I should provide at least a MWE, but I am new to latex and have absolutely no idea where to start.

[image]

MWE (Addition by HK)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}
\tikzset{
  %% fill styles if needed
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0)  {a};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This can certainly be done *by hand* (meaning defining all the lines explicitly, etc.) with a lot of work. There are ways of doing bar charts with pgfplots. You might be able to build up from there. See this example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185136/conditionally-transparent-surface-in-pgfplots

Comment: It's a pretty useless plot, since you cannot easily compare the different values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough approximation...I didn't try to replicate the numbers in the MWE and haven't finetuned the details.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

% \Yvalue{x-coordinate}{y-coordinate}{colour}
\newcommand\drawYvalue[3]{%
  \draw[fill=#3!30](#1,0,1)--++(-1,0,0)--++(0,#2,0)--++(1,0,0)--cycle;
  \draw[fill=#3!10](#1,#2,1)--++(-1,0,0)--++(0,0,-1)--++(1,0,0)--cycle;
  \draw[fill=#3!15](#1,0,1)--++(0,0,-1)--++(0,#2,0)--++(0,0,1)--cycle;
 }

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,4,8} {
    \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue!10]
           (\x,0,0)--++(2,0,0)--++(0,6,0)--++(-2,0,0)--cycle;
  }
  \foreach \x in {0,2,4,6} {
    \draw[blue!50](\x,0,2)--++(0,0,-2)--++(0,6,0);
  }
  \draw[blue!50](0,0,2)--++(0,6,0);
  \foreach \y in {0,2,4,6} {
    \draw[blue!50](10,\y,0)--++(-10,0,0)--++(0,0,2);
  }
  \foreach \y/\txt [count=\x]
    in {3/Label 1, 4/Label 2, 1/Label 3, 5/Label 4,6/Label 5} {
    \drawYvalue{2*\x-0.5}{\y}{\ifodd\x yellow\else green\fi}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
      \node[transform shape,rotate=180] at (3,2*\x-1)[anchor=west,align=right]{\txt};
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```