# imagesc in tikz with non-symmetric matrices and squared axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matrices

In principle the problem is the same like in [matlab2tikz imagesc TikZ/pgfplots equivalent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124276/matlab2tikz-imagesc-tikz-pgfplots-equivalent)

Can somebody tell me how to adopt this snippet to plot non-symmetric matrices but with squared axis (without any gaps inside)

As it should **not** look like, because of the gaps:[image]

As it should look **not** like, because of the rectangle axis:[image]

**Snipped:**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{cr3}{RGB}{177,11,69}
\definecolor{cr2}{RGB}{210,210,210}
\definecolor{cr1}{RGB}{121,154,153}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=newest,
  tick label style={font=\small},
  label style={font=\footnotesize},
  legend style={font=\scriptsize,fill=none,draw=none},
  every axis legend/.append style={legend image code/.code={\draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,##1]plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.1cm,0cm) (0.2cm,0cm)};}},
}%
%*** matrix-plot style
\pgfplotsset{%
  matrix plot/.style = {%
    axis on top,
    clip marker paths = true,
    scale only axis,
    % height = \nYdata//\nXdata/*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width},
    enlarge x limits = {rel=0.5/\nXdata/},
    enlarge y limits = {rel=0.5/\nYdata/},
    scatter/use mapped color = {draw=mapped color, fill=mapped color},
    scatter,
    point meta = explicit,
    mark = square*,
    cycle list = {%
        mark size=0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}/\nXdata/
    }
  },
}%  

%*** number definition
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/number format/set thousands separator={},
  /pgf/number format/set decimal separator={.}
}%

%*** data table information
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
  col sep=semicolon,
  x index=0,
  y index=1,
  header=false
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %*** definition of datasize
  \def\nXdata/{20},
  \def\nYdata/{6},
  %*** definition of limits
  \def\min/{0.5},
  \def\max/{1.5},
  \def\lb/{1.0},
  \def\ub/{1.0},
  %*** axis
  \begin{axis}[
      width=5cm,
      height=5cm,
      matrix plot,
      point meta min={\min/},
      point meta max={\max/},
      colormap={UIBK}{[0.1]
        color(\min/-\min/)=(cr1);
        color(\lb/-\min/)=(cr2);
        color(\ub/-\min/)=(cr2);
        color(\max/-\min/)=(cr3)},
      %*** colorbar
      colorbar horizontal,
      colorbar style = {%
        at={(0.0,1.30)},
        anchor=south west,
        width=1.0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width},
        height=0.3cm,
        xmin=\min/,
        xmax=\max/,
        xtick={\min/,\lb/,\ub/,\max/},
        mark = square*,},
      colorbar sampled line,
      %*** x-axis
      xlabel = {$n$},
      xmin = 1,
      xmax = 20,
      xtick = {1,5,10,15,20},
      %*** y-axis
      ylabel = {$\tau$},
      ymin = 1,
      ymax = 6,
      ytick = {1,2,3,4,5,6},
      yticklabels = {0.10,0.12,0.14,0.16,0.18,0.20},
    ]
      \addplot table [meta index=2] {1.000000;1.000000;1.051819
                                    1.000000;2.000000;1.000000
                                    1.000000;3.000000;1.000000
                                    1.000000;4.000000;1.000000
                                    1.000000;5.000000;1.012168
                                    1.000000;6.000000;0.988435

                                    2.000000;1.000000;0.953648
                                    2.000000;2.000000;0.945830
                                    2.000000;3.000000;0.967785
                                    2.000000;4.000000;0.980390
                                    2.000000;5.000000;0.957779
                                    2.000000;6.000000;0.973894

                                    3.000000;1.000000;0.962710
                                    3.000000;2.000000;0.949404
                                    3.000000;3.000000;0.959728
                                    3.000000;4.000000;0.972972
                                    3.000000;5.000000;0.963546
                                    3.000000;6.000000;0.979361

                                    4.000000;1.000000;0.959866
                                    4.000000;2.000000;0.984708
                                    4.000000;3.000000;0.961893
                                    4.000000;4.000000;0.998287
                                    4.000000;5.000000;0.968716
                                    4.000000;6.000000;0.962727

                                    5.000000;1.000000;0.973517
                                    5.000000;2.000000;0.975561
                                    5.000000;3.000000;0.976335
                                    5.000000;4.000000;0.976228
                                    5.000000;5.000000;0.983381
                                    5.000000;6.000000;0.968988

                                    6.000000;1.000000;0.966111
                                    6.000000;2.000000;0.984690
                                    6.000000;3.000000;0.947801
                                    6.000000;4.000000;0.984505
                                    6.000000;5.000000;0.964116
                                    6.000000;6.000000;0.972827

                                    7.000000;1.000000;0.993063
                                    7.000000;2.000000;0.953702
                                    7.000000;3.000000;0.996289
                                    7.000000;4.000000;0.970655
                                    7.000000;5.000000;0.957275
                                    7.000000;6.000000;0.925806

                                    8.000000;1.000000;0.958390
                                    8.000000;2.000000;0.998144
                                    8.000000;3.000000;0.974472
                                    8.000000;4.000000;0.954414
                                    8.000000;5.000000;0.949770
                                    8.000000;6.000000;0.918929

                                    9.000000;1.000000;0.998319
                                    9.000000;2.000000;0.980637
                                    9.000000;3.000000;0.966380
                                    9.000000;4.000000;0.973852
                                    9.000000;5.000000;0.931611
                                    9.000000;6.000000;0.939964

                                    10.000000;1.000000;1.009831
                                    10.000000;2.000000;0.997056
                                    10.000000;3.000000;0.971533
                                    10.000000;4.000000;0.950970
                                    10.000000;5.000000;0.984151
                                    10.000000;6.000000;0.939601

                                    11.000000;1.000000;0.991757
                                    11.000000;2.000000;0.986907
                                    11.000000;3.000000;0.970439
                                    11.000000;4.000000;1.000952
                                    11.000000;5.000000;0.982607
                                    11.000000;6.000000;0.963821

                                    12.000000;1.000000;1.030766
                                    12.000000;2.000000;1.012735
                                    12.000000;3.000000;1.000013
                                    12.000000;4.000000;1.014096
                                    12.000000;5.000000;0.973391
                                    12.000000;6.000000;0.984517

                                    13.000000;1.000000;1.020537
                                    13.000000;2.000000;0.997647
                                    13.000000;3.000000;1.035671
                                    13.000000;4.000000;0.998183
                                    13.000000;5.000000;0.995325
                                    13.000000;6.000000;0.975726

                                    14.000000;1.000000;1.033529
                                    14.000000;2.000000;1.026951
                                    14.000000;3.000000;1.039208
                                    14.000000;4.000000;1.001587
                                    14.000000;5.000000;0.985112
                                    14.000000;6.000000;1.029229

                                    15.000000;1.000000;1.004259
                                    15.000000;2.000000;1.049424
                                    15.000000;3.000000;1.017412
                                    15.000000;4.000000;1.006954
                                    15.000000;5.000000;1.012810
                                    15.000000;6.000000;1.084488

                                    16.000000;1.000000;1.026232
                                    16.000000;2.000000;1.073393
                                    16.000000;3.000000;1.032529
                                    16.000000;4.000000;1.010247
                                    16.000000;5.000000;1.031920
                                    16.000000;6.000000;1.059238

                                    17.000000;1.000000;1.049910
                                    17.000000;2.000000;1.027786
                                    17.000000;3.000000;1.018022
                                    17.000000;4.000000;1.015627
                                    17.000000;5.000000;1.113215
                                    17.000000;6.000000;1.080651

                                    18.000000;1.000000;1.065341
                                    18.000000;2.000000;1.041362
                                    18.000000;3.000000;1.011830
                                    18.000000;4.000000;1.058460
                                    18.000000;5.000000;1.069346
                                    18.000000;6.000000;1.058428

                                    19.000000;1.000000;1.095343
                                    19.000000;2.000000;1.021611
                                    19.000000;3.000000;1.031146
                                    19.000000;4.000000;1.122735
                                    19.000000;5.000000;1.098571
                                    19.000000;6.000000;1.088736

                                    20.000000;1.000000;1.065167
                                    20.000000;2.000000;1.005796
                                    20.000000;3.000000;1.051143
                                    20.000000;4.000000;1.078253
                                    20.000000;5.000000;1.080351
                                    20.000000;6.000000;1.069805
                                    };
  \end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

color modification implemented ([Scaling colormaps with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/scaling-colormaps-with-pgfplots)).

Comment: For the additional question on setting the limits of the colourmaps, see [Scaling colormaps with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/scaling-colormaps-with-pgfplots)

Comment: Please don't remove the question to which you've got an answer. That just makes it virtually impossible for anybody else to find an answer to the same question. It seems like this question should probably be split up. You should likely ask about the bit @Jake answered here, ask Jake to answer, and then ask the other question(s) separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, and using a 'matlab-translated' version of the python script of [Conditionally transparent surface in PGFPLOTS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185136/conditionally-transparent-surface-in-pgfplots) i managed it :) [image]

**Source code:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{cr3}{RGB}{177,11,69}
\definecolor{cr2}{RGB}{210,210,210}
\definecolor{cr1}{RGB}{121,154,153}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
  col sep=semicolon,
  x index=0,
  y index=1,
  header=false
}%

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\min/{0.5},
    \def\max/{1.5},
    \def\lb/{1.0},
    \def\ub/{1.0},
    \begin{axis}[
        %*** general
        % view = {-40}{30}, %3D
        view = {0}{90}, %2D
        width=5cm,
        height=5cm,
        unbounded coords = jump,
        %*** colormap
        point meta min={\min/},
        point meta max={\max/},
        colormap={UIBK}{[0.1]
          color(\min/-\min/)=(cr1);
          color(\lb/-\min/)=(cr2);
          color(\ub/-\min/)=(cr2);
          color(\max/-\min/)=(cr3)},
        %*** colorbar
        colorbar,
        colorbar style = {%
          at={(1.1,0.0)},
          anchor=south west,
          height=1.0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height},
          width=0.2cm,
          ymin=\min/,
          ymax=\max/,
          ytick={\min/,\lb/,\ub/,\max/},
          mark = square*,},
        %*** x-axis
        xlabel = {$n$},
        xmin = 1,
        xmax = 21,
        xtick = {1,5,10,15,20},
        xticklabels = {1,5,10,15,20},
        x tick label style={xshift=2,yshift=0},
        %*** y-axis
        ylabel = {$\theta-\alpha$},
        ymin = 1,
        ymax = 9,
        ytick = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
        yticklabels = {0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40},
        y tick label style={xshift=0,yshift=6},
        %*** zmin
        zmin=\min/,
        zmax=\max/,
      ]
        \addplot3[surf,mark=none,mesh/cols=48,faceted color=gray,very thin] table {data/(n_thal)(2)(M_2_Mima_CCp50)(IM-i)(tau0.20)(ATC63)(Bilin)(4strsti)(R).csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the transparency stuff the solution is quite straigth forward with the `matrix plot*` feature of PGFPlots v1.13 (section 4.6.12 on page 168 of the manual). I simplified your example a little bit so it is easier to see the main points.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{cr3}{RGB}{177,11,69}
    \definecolor{cr2}{RGB}{210,210,210}
    \definecolor{cr1}{RGB}{121,154,153}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableset{%
        col sep=semicolon,
        x index=0,
        y index=1,
        header=false
    }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\min/{0.92},     % originally: 0.5
        \def\max/{1.12},     % originally: 1.5
        \def\lb/{1.0},
        \def\ub/{1.0},
    \begin{axis}[
        %*** general
        width=5cm,
        height=5cm,
        %*** colormap
        point meta min={\min/},
        point meta max={\max/},
        colormap={UIBK}{    % simplified to match non-uniform distances around 1
            color=(cr1);
            color=(cr2);
            color=(cr3);
        },
        %*** colorbar
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={
            ytick={\min/,\lb/,\ub/,\max/},
        },
        %*** x-axis
        xlabel={$n$},
        xmin=1,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={1,5,10,15,20},
        %*** y-axis
        ylabel={$\theta-\alpha$},
        ymin=1,
        ymax=6,
        ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
        yticklabels={0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40},
        %
        point meta=explicit,        % to use explicitly given meta values
        axis on top,                % otherwise you won't see the ticks
        enlargelimits={abs=0.5},    % increase axis limits half a step width
                                    % which is the part drawn to each side at
                                    % each given point
        % if you want to draw a grid uncomment and adapt me
        %faceted color=mapped color!80!black,
    ]

        \addplot [
            matrix plot*,
            % if you want to draw a grid uncomment me, too
            %shader=faceted,
        ] table [meta index=2] {
            1.000000;1.000000;1.051819
            1.000000;2.000000;1.000000
            1.000000;3.000000;1.000000
            1.000000;4.000000;1.000000
            1.000000;5.000000;1.012168
            1.000000;6.000000;0.988435

            2.000000;1.000000;0.953648
            2.000000;2.000000;0.945830
            2.000000;3.000000;0.967785
            2.000000;4.000000;0.980390
            2.000000;5.000000;0.957779
            2.000000;6.000000;0.973894

            3.000000;1.000000;0.962710
            3.000000;2.000000;0.949404
            3.000000;3.000000;0.959728
            3.000000;4.000000;0.972972
            3.000000;5.000000;0.963546
            3.000000;6.000000;0.979361

            4.000000;1.000000;0.959866
            4.000000;2.000000;0.984708
            4.000000;3.000000;0.961893
            4.000000;4.000000;0.998287
            4.000000;5.000000;0.968716
            4.000000;6.000000;0.962727

            5.000000;1.000000;0.973517
            5.000000;2.000000;0.975561
            5.000000;3.000000;0.976335
            5.000000;4.000000;0.976228
            5.000000;5.000000;0.983381
            5.000000;6.000000;0.968988

            6.000000;1.000000;0.966111
            6.000000;2.000000;0.984690
            6.000000;3.000000;0.947801
            6.000000;4.000000;0.984505
            6.000000;5.000000;0.964116
            6.000000;6.000000;0.972827

            7.000000;1.000000;0.993063
            7.000000;2.000000;0.953702
            7.000000;3.000000;0.996289
            7.000000;4.000000;0.970655
            7.000000;5.000000;0.957275
            7.000000;6.000000;0.925806

            8.000000;1.000000;0.958390
            8.000000;2.000000;0.998144
            8.000000;3.000000;0.974472
            8.000000;4.000000;0.954414
            8.000000;5.000000;0.949770
            8.000000;6.000000;0.918929

            9.000000;1.000000;0.998319
            9.000000;2.000000;0.980637
            9.000000;3.000000;0.966380
            9.000000;4.000000;0.973852
            9.000000;5.000000;0.931611
            9.000000;6.000000;0.939964

            10.000000;1.000000;1.009831
            10.000000;2.000000;0.997056
            10.000000;3.000000;0.971533
            10.000000;4.000000;0.950970
            10.000000;5.000000;0.984151
            10.000000;6.000000;0.939601

            11.000000;1.000000;0.991757
            11.000000;2.000000;0.986907
            11.000000;3.000000;0.970439
            11.000000;4.000000;1.000952
            11.000000;5.000000;0.982607
            11.000000;6.000000;0.963821

            12.000000;1.000000;1.030766
            12.000000;2.000000;1.012735
            12.000000;3.000000;1.000013
            12.000000;4.000000;1.014096
            12.000000;5.000000;0.973391
            12.000000;6.000000;0.984517

            13.000000;1.000000;1.020537
            13.000000;2.000000;0.997647
            13.000000;3.000000;1.035671
            13.000000;4.000000;0.998183
            13.000000;5.000000;0.995325
            13.000000;6.000000;0.975726

            14.000000;1.000000;1.033529
            14.000000;2.000000;1.026951
            14.000000;3.000000;1.039208
            14.000000;4.000000;1.001587
            14.000000;5.000000;0.985112
            14.000000;6.000000;1.029229

            15.000000;1.000000;1.004259
            15.000000;2.000000;1.049424
            15.000000;3.000000;1.017412
            15.000000;4.000000;1.006954
            15.000000;5.000000;1.012810
            15.000000;6.000000;1.084488

            16.000000;1.000000;1.026232
            16.000000;2.000000;1.073393
            16.000000;3.000000;1.032529
            16.000000;4.000000;1.010247
            16.000000;5.000000;1.031920
            16.000000;6.000000;1.059238

            17.000000;1.000000;1.049910
            17.000000;2.000000;1.027786
            17.000000;3.000000;1.018022
            17.000000;4.000000;1.015627
            17.000000;5.000000;1.113215
            17.000000;6.000000;1.080651

            18.000000;1.000000;1.065341
            18.000000;2.000000;1.041362
            18.000000;3.000000;1.011830
            18.000000;4.000000;1.058460
            18.000000;5.000000;1.069346
            18.000000;6.000000;1.058428

            19.000000;1.000000;1.095343
            19.000000;2.000000;1.021611
            19.000000;3.000000;1.031146
            19.000000;4.000000;1.122735
            19.000000;5.000000;1.098571
            19.000000;6.000000;1.088736

            20.000000;1.000000;1.065167
            20.000000;2.000000;1.005796
            20.000000;3.000000;1.051143
            20.000000;4.000000;1.078253
            20.000000;5.000000;1.080351
            20.000000;6.000000;1.069805
        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]