# graph on latex with too many data points, giving me timeout

Tags: pgfplots, tex-core, graphs, tikz-pic

So, I am writing a report which contains graphs, graphs are with a huge amount of data points.
one graph only could contain more than 32,000 points, and I am using tikzpicture and adding coordinates to the plot. overleaf gives me timeout each time, even though I have a premium account, what can I do. is there a way to separate the graphs alone to be compiled separately, so I can finish my report.

Thank you for concerning, and helping :)

Comment: This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248723/plot-large-data has an answer for me that can help you. There is really no need to plot 32000 points, unless you want to print a billboard at 300dpi...

Comment: I thought `externalize` could probably help. Render the image once and not every compilation. This needs certain settings in Overleaf

Comment: Found the settings needed https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz,_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures,_so_I'm_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a Minimum Working Example (MWE)?  I do all my graphs separately, and then add them as pdf's with \includegraphics, so I can play with the details separately, and then not have to re-do (and possibly munge) them.

I'm assuming you're using pgfplots, but a small example would help us help.  (and from experience,  help you by isolating the specific issue...)

OK, you might also search for "tikz externalize", which might get you past your current issue, but has it's own issues.

Cheers

Mike