(pgfplots) How to plot every Nth entry from a large CSV file?
I have a large csv file (20,000 entries) and I am having compiling issues. I figure a good way to solve this is to skip certain entries e.g. plotting only every 100th entry. However I am unsure how to go about this.
This is the code that I have so far.
\addplot[mark=none, color={black!50}, line width=1.0] table [col sep=comma, header=true, x expr=\coordindex, y index=1] {path/file.csv};

Welcome to TeX.SE!  Axis option each nth point should help, see package documentation, page 397. For more help please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we cab test as it is.

@Zarko is correct, but beware of aliasing: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318524/38080

@Rmano, you are right (your answer there is very nice, +1). I thing now that question is duplicate to question in your giving link!
