# Adding 3d axis to a 3dplot figure

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I have 3D surface plot obtained from matlab. I would like to add axes to it with labels using latex. What is the proper way of doing this? Or do I have to just guess and draw lines (trail and error).

Axis limit: Frequency: 0 to 3000 Hz; Time 0 to 3 secs.

The plot figure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: what are the axis limits in numbers?

Comment: Of topic question: On the PSD level you have dB/Hz, but the time-frequency plot looks like a wide-band generated signal. Then for -30 dB/Hz you have the order of mW/Hz, which is quite high. Is it completely wrong to assume it should be dBm/Hz?

Comment: @percusse: I thought that any arbitrary axis limit would be enough for this question.  I edited my question to include it.

Comment: @StefanH: Sorry! I do not understand your question.

Comment: See the pgfplots manual for `\addplot graphics` key also this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots

Comment: Sorry. With the scaling of the frequency axis I see that I am really off topic

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a typical or proper way to do it. Usually I put the plot in a picture or, as below, a tikzpicture and put a grid above it. Then it is easier to navigate. When started it is pretty quick to find the right coordinates for the axis. Below is an example of how to put it. If in a normal picture environment you can also use the `graphpap` package to draw the grid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) node[anchor=south west]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{PaintBrush.jpg}};
  \draw[step=1cm,green,thin] (0mm,0mm) grid (50mm,60mm);
  \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm] (20mm,10mm) -- +(0mm,45mm)node[left]{Power};
  \draw(0,0)circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]